# How to get the error message from the error code returned by GetLastError()?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

After a Windows API call, how can I get the last error message in a textual form?

`GetLastError()` returns an integer value, not a text message.

Comment: there use to be an exe error lookup in the tool section in visual studio which do this pretty well when you only need message from error for debugging.

Comment: @ColdCat: For debugging it's a lot easier to just add a `@err,hr` watch, and have the debugger automatically convert the last error code to a human-readable representation. The `,hr` format specifier works for any expression that evaluates to an integral value, e.g. a `5,hr` watch will display *"ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED : Access is denied."*.

Comment: From the [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) documentation: "*To obtain an error string for system error codes, use the `FormatMessage()` function.*". See the [Retrieving the Last-Error Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582.aspx) example on MSDN.

Answer (score 218):

```
//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //Get the error message ID, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if(errorMessageID == 0) {
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded
    }
    
    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;

    //Ask Win32 to give us the string version of that message ID.
    //The parameters we pass in, tell Win32 to create the buffer that holds the message for us (because we don't yet know how long the message string will be).
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);
    
    //Copy the error message into a std::string.
    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);
    
    //Free the Win32's string's buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);
            
    return message;
}
```

Comment: I believe you actually need to pass `(LPSTR)&messageBuffer` in this case, as otherwise there's no way FormatMessageA could alter its value to point to the allocated buffer.

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah that is kinda weird. How would it modify the pointer? But passing it the pointer's address (pointer-to-a-pointer), but casting it to a regular pointer... Win32 weirdness. Thanks for the heads up, fixed it in my own code base (and my answer). Very subtle catch.

Comment: Will this using `FormatMessageA()` works on a system in french language?

Comment: I'm not sure. It doesn't support Unicode - you can rewrite it to use std::wstring and FormatMessageW() - but I don't work with Unicode or Widechars myself, so I wouldn't know for sure how to go about that.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example is much clearer than the one from MSDN. More over, the one from MSDN even couldn't compile. It includes some `strsafe.h` header, that isn't *safe* at all, it causing a bunch of a compiler errors in `winuser.h` and `winbase.h`.

Comment: Some error IDs are not supported. For example, 0x2EE7, ERROR_INTERNET_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED causes a new error when calling FormatMessage: 0x13D, The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

Comment: I guess the cast to (LPSTR) is not strictly needed.

Comment: Issues with this implementation: `1` `GetLastError` is potentially called too late. `2` No Unicode support. `3` Use of exceptions without implementing exception safety guarantees.

Comment: @Zitrax The cast is needed, because (as Kylotan points out), when **FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER** is passed in, the function internally treats the LPSTR to a LPSTR* (a pointer-to-a-pointer), which is why we need to get the *address* of the LPSTR (i.e. an address to a pointer), and cast it to an LPSTR. Blame Microsoft, but it is necessary. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: _For example, 0x2EE7, ERROR_INTERNET_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED causes a new error when calling FormatMessage_ - For errors returned from WinInet API, you have to pass a handle to "wininet.dll" for the 2nd parameter of `FormatMessage()`, as described on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383884(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 75):

*Updated (11/2017) to take into consideration some comments.*

Easy example:

```
wchar_t buf[256];
FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
               NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
               buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
```

Comment: I just noticed: why do you use wchar_t? Probably it should be just a `char*`, cuz my compiler gives me an error `cannot convert ‘wchar_t*’ to ‘LPSTR {aka char*}’ for argument ‘5’`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - The example assumes that you're compiling with UNICODE defined.  'FormatMessage' is actually a macro that expands to either 'FormatMessageA' for Ansi/MBCS character buffers, or 'FormatMessageW' for UTF16/UNICODE buffers, depending on how the application is compiled.  I took the liberty of editing the example above to explicitly invoke the version that matches the output buffer type (wchar_t).

Comment: Add FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS: "If you are not in control of the format string, then you must pass FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS to prevent the %1 from causing trouble." https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071128-00/?p=24353

Comment: Issues with this implementation: `1` Failure to specify the important `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag. `2` `GetLastError` potentially called too late. `3` Arbitrary restriction of the message to 256 code units. `4` No error handling.

Comment: sizeof(buf) should be ARRAYSIZE(buf) since FormatMessage expects the size of the buffer in TCHARs, not in bytes.

Comment: Indeed it should @Kai

Comment: Can't we use of `256` instead of `(sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)`? does it acceptable and safe?

Answer (score 44):

Since c++11, you can use the standard library instead of `FormatMessage`:

```cpp
#include <system_error>

if (!SomeWin32Function()){
   DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
   std::string message = std::system_category().message(error);
   ...
}
```

Comment: There's only a tiny window where calling `GetLastError` produces a meaningful result. With this being C++, the only safe option here is to have the caller provide the last error code. It certainly doesn't help, that the code presented calls `GetLastError` *twice*. Also, while convenient, C++' inherent lack of wide character support fails to make the `error_category` interface universally useful. This just adds to C++' long history of missed opportunities.

Comment: Good point about the useless call to `GetLastError`. But I see not difference between calling `GetLastError` here or having the caller call it. Regarding C++ and wchar: Don't abandon hope, Microsoft is starting to [allow apps to be UTF-8 only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).

Comment: *"I see no difference"* - Consider the following call site: `log_error("error", GetLastErrorAsString());`. Also consider that `log_error`'s first argument is of type `std::string`. The (invisible) conversion c'tor call just dropped your guarantees to capture a meaningful value from `GetLastError` at the point you are calling it.

Comment: Why do you think that the std::string constructor calls a Win32 function?

Comment: A `std::string` allocates memory to store its controlled sequence. A memory allocation will eventually wind up calling into the OS. The point isn't so much about `std::string` as it is to illustrate, that C++ is riddled with *invisible* code. The proposed signature here just acts as an invitation to implement bugs. And you cannot even see the bug by looking at the `log_error` call. To see it, a reviewer would have to look into both the `log_error` and `GetLastErrorAsString` implementations, in addition to the call site.

Comment: That is actually not a problem – [malloc calls `HeapAlloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111178/758345), which [does not call `SetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc#return-value). I agree that the world could be better, but I don't think claiming there are problems in places where there aren't is helpful.

Comment: `malloc` calls `HeapAlloc` for the process heap. The process heap is growable. If it needs to grow, it will ultimately call [VirtualAlloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc), which *does* set the calling thread's last error code. Now that's totally missing the point, which is: C++ is a minefield. This implementation just adds to that, by providing an interface with implied guarantees it simply cannot live up to. If you believe that there is no problem, it should be easy for you to *prove* the proposed solution's correctness. Good luck.

Comment: It should be the responsibility of HeapAlloc to preserve the OS error state. It's also a leap to assume that HepaAlloc would call VirtualAlloc internally - it may call any variant of internal virtual allocation functions which behave similarly to the user-facing VirtualAlloc and which may expressly avoid calling SetLastError in order to preserve the accuracy of the docs, which state that HeapAlloc does not SetLastError. 

Moreover, if VirtualAlloc fails when trying to resize heap for a small string, then you've got worse things to worry about than GetLastError being wrong.

Comment: @jstine You're reading something into the documentation that's not there. `HeapAlloc` isn't documented to preserve the calling thread's last error code. As for `VirtualAlloc`, like any other Windows API call, it can change the last error code during normal operation. It is rather the responsibility of the developer to read the documentation, and decide when `GetLastError` will return a meaningful value. In case of `HeapAlloc` that's easy: It won't, ever.

Answer (score 23):

[GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) returns a numerical error code. To obtain a descriptive error message (e.g., to display to a user), you can call [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx):

```
// This functions fills a caller-defined character buffer (pBuffer)
// of max length (cchBufferLength) with the human-readable error message
// for a Win32 error code (dwErrorCode).
// 
// Returns TRUE if successful, or FALSE otherwise.
// If successful, pBuffer is guaranteed to be NUL-terminated.
// On failure, the contents of pBuffer are undefined.
BOOL GetErrorMessage(DWORD dwErrorCode, LPTSTR pBuffer, DWORD cchBufferLength)
{
    if (cchBufferLength == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD cchMsg = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL,  /* (not used with FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM) */
                                 dwErrorCode,
                                 MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                                 pBuffer,
                                 cchBufferLength,
                                 NULL);
    return (cchMsg > 0);
}
```

In C++, you can simplify the interface considerably by using the std::string class:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <system_error>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> String;

String GetErrorMessage(DWORD dwErrorCode)
{
    LPTSTR psz{ nullptr };
    const DWORD cchMsg = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
                                         | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS
                                         | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
                                       NULL, // (not used with FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM)
                                       dwErrorCode,
                                       MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                                       reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&psz),
                                       0,
                                       NULL);
    if (cchMsg > 0)
    {
        // Assign buffer to smart pointer with custom deleter so that memory gets released
        // in case String's c'tor throws an exception.
        auto deleter = [](void* p) { ::LocalFree(p); };
        std::unique_ptr<TCHAR, decltype(deleter)> ptrBuffer(psz, deleter);
        return String(ptrBuffer.get(), cchMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        auto error_code{ ::GetLastError() };
        throw std::system_error( error_code, std::system_category(),
                                 "Failed to retrieve error message string.");
    }
}
```

NOTE: These functions also work for HRESULT values. Just change the first parameter from DWORD dwErrorCode to HRESULT hResult. The rest of the code can remain unchanged.

---

These implementations provide the following improvements over the existing answers:

- Complete sample code, not just a reference to the API to call.
- Provides both C and C++ implementations.
- Works for both Unicode and MBCS project settings.
- Takes the error code as an input parameter. This is important, as a thread's last error code is only valid at well defined points. An input parameter allows the caller to follow the documented contract.
- Implements proper exception safety. Unlike all of the other solutions that implicitly use exceptions, this implementation will not leak memory in case an exception is thrown while constructing the return value.
- Proper use of the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag. See [The importance of the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071128-00/?p=24353) for more information.
- Proper error handling/error reporting, unlike some of the other answers, that silently ignore errors.

---

*This answer has been incorporated from Stack Overflow Documentation. The following users have contributed to the example: [stackptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469027/stackptr), [Ajay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264325/ajay), [Cody Gray♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray), [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable).*

Comment: Instead of throwing `std::runtime_error`, I suggest to throw `std::system_error(lastError, std::system_category(), "Failed to retrieve error message string.")` where `lastError` would be the return value of `GetLastError()` after the failed `FormatMessage()` call.

Comment: What is the advantage of using your C version over `FormatMessage` directly?

Comment: @mic: That's like asking: *"What is the advantage of functions in C?"* Functions reduce complexity by providing abstractions. In this case, the abstraction reduces the number of parameters from 7 to 3, implements the documented contract of the API by passing compatible flags and parameters, and encodes the documented error reporting logic. It provides a concise interface, with easy to guess semantics, sparing you the need to invest 11 minutes to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage).

Comment: I like this answer, it's very clear that careful attention has been paid to the correctness of the code. I have two questions. 1) Why do you use `::HeapFree(::GetProcessHeap(), 0, p)` in the deleter instead of `::LocalFree(p)` as the documentation suggests? 2) I realize that the documentation says to do it this way, but doesn't `reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&psz)` violate the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @teh: Thank you for the feedback. Question 1): Honestly, I don't know if this is safe. I don't recall, who or why the call to `HeapFree` was introduced, while this was still a topic in SO Documentation. I'll have to investigate (although the documentation seems to be clear, that this is *not* safe). Question 2): This is two-fold. For an MBCS configuration, `LPTSTR` is an alias for `char*`. That cast is always safe. For a Unicode configuration, casting to `wchar_t*` is fishy at any rate. I don't know if this is safe in C, but it's most likely not in C++. I'd have to investigate this, too.

Comment: @teh: Since I just had reason to re-visit the ins and outs of the strict aliasing rule, here is the answer to your 2nd question: No, this is not a violation. The strict aliasing rule applies to *access*. As long as you don't access an object through a pointer, you can re-type this pointer to your heart's content, so long as you only access the object through a pointer to the object's dynamic (or compatible) type. Casting to `void*` is a common way to implement type erasure, and it's even used in the Standard Library, e.g. with [std::qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: @teh: I also changed the implementation to agree with the documentation. Apparently, calling `HeapFree` [is safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage#parameters) (starting with Windows 10, anyway), but `LocalFree` is never wrong, even if potentially more expensive.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the follow up! The Win32 API is a tricky beast for sure!

Answer (score 21):

MSDN has some sample code that demonstrates how to use `FormatMessage()` and `GetLastError()` together: [Retrieving the Last-Error Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680582%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

[FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx) will turn [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx)'s integer return into a text message.

Answer (score 12):

In general, you need to use `FormatMessage` to convert from a Win32 error code to text.

From the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Formats a message string. The function
>   requires a message definition as
>   input. The message definition can come
>   from a buffer passed into the
>   function. It can come from a message
>   table resource in an already-loaded
>   module. Or the caller can ask the
>   function to search the system's
>   message table resource(s) for the
>   message definition. The function finds
>   the message definition in a message
>   table resource based on a message
>   identifier and a language identifier.
>   The function copies the formatted
>   message text to an output buffer,
>   processing any embedded insert
>   sequences if requested.

The declaration of FormatMessage:

```
DWORD WINAPI FormatMessage(
  __in      DWORD dwFlags,
  __in_opt  LPCVOID lpSource,
  __in      DWORD dwMessageId, // your error code
  __in      DWORD dwLanguageId,
  __out     LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  __in      DWORD nSize,
  __in_opt  va_list *Arguments
);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using c# you can use this code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class WinErrors
{
    #region definitions
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int FormatMessage(FormatMessageFlags dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, uint dwMessageId, uint dwLanguageId, ref IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr Arguments);

    [Flags]
    private enum FormatMessageFlags : uint
    {
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = 0x00000100,
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = 0x00000200,
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x00001000,
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY = 0x00002000,
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE = 0x00000800,
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING = 0x00000400,
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a user friendly string message for a system error code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorCode">System error code</param>
    /// <returns>Error string</returns>
    public static string GetSystemMessage(int errorCode)
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr lpMsgBuf = IntPtr.Zero;

            int dwChars = FormatMessage(
                FormatMessageFlags.FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FormatMessageFlags.FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FormatMessageFlags.FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                (uint) errorCode,
                0, // Default language
                ref lpMsgBuf,
                0,
                IntPtr.Zero);
            if (dwChars == 0)
            {
                // Handle the error.
                int le = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                return "Unable to get error code string from System - Error " + le.ToString();
            }

            string sRet = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lpMsgBuf);

            // Free the buffer.
            lpMsgBuf = LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
            return sRet;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Unable to get error code string from System -> " + e.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirmed this code works. Shouldn't TS accepted this answer?

Comment: If it's necessary for a further throwing there is a [simpler way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/25/56643.aspx) to do it in C# with Win32Exception

Comment: @swdev: Why should anyone accept an answer in C# to a question tagged [tag:c] or [tag:c++]? As it stands, this answer doesn't even address the question being asked.

Comment: Well, I don't recall having voted on this proposed answer. I addressed the obvious flaw in @swdev's logic. But since you aren't going to believe me, I am now going to prove it to you: Here, have another down-vote. That one is from me, because this answer - while it may be useful given a different question - simply isn't useful given the question that was being asked.

Comment: *"I guess you have helpful insights to offer beyond the obvious"* - [Indeed, I have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329).

Answer (score 4):

If you need to support MBCS as well as Unicode, Mr.C64's answer is not quite enough. The buffer must be declared TCHAR, and cast to LPTSTR. Note that this code doesn't deal with the annoying newline that Microsoft appends to the error message.

```
CString FormatErrorMessage(DWORD ErrorCode)
{
    TCHAR   *pMsgBuf = NULL;
    DWORD   nMsgLen = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, ErrorCode, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&pMsgBuf), 0, NULL);
    if (!nMsgLen)
        return _T("FormatMessage fail");
    CString sMsg(pMsgBuf, nMsgLen);
    LocalFree(pMsgBuf);
    return sMsg;
}
```

Also, for brevity I find the following method useful:

```
CString GetLastErrorString()
{
    return FormatErrorMessage(GetLastError());
}
```

Comment: In case the `CString` c'tor throws an exception, this implementation leaks the memory allocated by the call to `FormatMessage`.

Comment: True, but I've used this code for many years and it's never been a problem. The only case in which the CString ctor is likely to throw is failure to allocate memory, and most MFC code--including the Microsoft-provided stuff--doesn't handle out of memory conditions as gracefully as you might like. Luckily most PCs now have so much memory that you have to work pretty hard to use it all. Any usage that generates a temporary CString instance (including returning a CString) runs this risk. It's a risk/convenience trade-off. Also if it happens in a message handler, the exception will be caught.

Comment: Most of this comment is wrong, sorry. *"It never happened to me"* is a damn weak point to make, especially when you know how the code can fail. The amount of memory has no impact on the available address space allotted to a process either. RAM is just a performance optimization. Copy-elision prevents allocation of a temporary, when code is written to allow NRVO. Whether or not exceptions are caught in a message handler depends on the process bitness and external settings. I have submitted an answer that shows, that risk management doesn't lead to inconvenience.

Comment: Besides, the risk of running out of memory in constructing a temporary is moot. At that point all resources have been freed, and nothing bad will come of it.

Comment: No I'm sorry the code isn't useful to you. But TBH it's pretty low on my list of problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
void WinErrorCodeToString(DWORD ErrorCode, string& Message)
{
char* locbuffer = NULL;
DWORD count = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, NULL, ErrorCode,
    0, (LPSTR)&locbuffer, 0, nullptr);
if (locbuffer)
{
    if (count)
    {
        int c;
        int back = 0;
        //
        // strip any trailing "\r\n"s and replace by a single "\n"
        //
        while (((c = *CharPrevA(locbuffer, locbuffer + count)) == '\r') ||
            (c == '\n')) {
            count--;
            back++;
        }

        if (back) {
            locbuffer[count++] = '\n';
            locbuffer[count] = '\0';
        }

        Message = "Error: ";
        Message += locbuffer;
    }
    LocalFree(locbuffer);
}
else
{
    Message = "Unknown error code: " + to_string(ErrorCode);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you also add some explanation?

Comment: Issues with this implementation: `1` No Unicode support. `2` Inappropriate formatting of the error message. If the caller needs to process the returned string, it can just do so. Your implementation leaves the caller with no option. `3` Use of exceptions but lack of proper exception safety. In case the `std::string` operators throw exceptions, the buffer allocated by `FormatMessage` is leaked. `4` Why not simply return a `std::string` instead of having the caller pass an object by reference?

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution

Here is my minimal C++ example using std::string/wstring.

- Works with both Unicode and MBCS
- Compatible from MSVC 6.0 -> VS2022 and GCC/MinGW (with -lstdc++). Most likely with Clang too.
- Doesn't require C++11
- Works in Windows XP and later.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> String;

String errorMessage(DWORD dwError)
{
    LPTSTR lpBuffer = NULL;
    String ret = TEXT("");
    if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwError, 0, (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer, 0, NULL))
        ret = String(lpBuffer);
    LocalFree(lpBuffer);
    return ret;
}
```

It doesn't have any error checking though and just returns an empty string if it can't find the specified error. You can implement your own error checking if you like.

*Why waste time write lot code, when few code do trick?*

---

##### Additional information <sup>(you can skip this)</sup>

I pass 0 for dwLanguageId as it's the right way to do it, as other answers failed to notice that MAKELANGID macro is deprecated and **should not be used** as it is inconsistent and doesn't work at all for some languages.

Here is an excerpt from winnt.h in Windows SDK 10.0.19041.0 (2020-05-12) stating the issue:

```cpp
//
// ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED **
//
//  DEPRECATED: The LCID/LANGID/SORTID concept is deprecated, please use
//  Locale Names instead, eg: "en-US" instead of an LCID like 0x0409.
//  See the documentation for GetLocaleInfoEx.
//
//  A language ID is a 16 bit value which is the combination of a
//  primary language ID and a secondary language ID.  The bits are
//  allocated as follows:
//
//       +-----------------------+-------------------------+
//       |     Sublanguage ID    |   Primary Language ID   |
//       +-----------------------+-------------------------+
//        15                   10 9                       0   bit
//
//  WARNING:  This pattern is broken and not followed for all languages.
//            Serbian, Bosnian & Croatian are a few examples.
//
//  WARNING:  There are > 6000 human languages.  The PRIMARYLANGID construct
//            cannot support all languages your application may encounter.
//            Please use Language Names, such as "en".
//
//  WARNING:  There are > 200 country-regions.  The SUBLANGID construct cannot
//            represent all valid dialects of languages such as English.
//            Please use Locale Names, such as "en-US".
//
//  WARNING:  Some languages may have more than one PRIMARYLANGID.  Please
//            use Locale Names, such as "en-FJ".
//
//  WARNING:  Some languages do not have assigned LANGIDs.  Please use
//            Locale Names, such as "tlh-Piqd".
//
//  It is recommended that applications test for locale names rather than
//  attempting to construct/deconstruct LANGID/PRIMARYLANGID/SUBLANGID
//
//  Language ID creation/extraction macros:
//
//    MAKELANGID    - construct language id from a primary language id and
//                    a sublanguage id.
//    PRIMARYLANGID - extract primary language id from a language id.
//    SUBLANGID     - extract sublanguage id from a language id.
//
//  Note that the LANG, SUBLANG construction is not always consistent.
//  The named locale APIs (eg GetLocaleInfoEx) are recommended.
//
//  DEPRECATED: Language IDs do not exist for all locales
//
// ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED ** DEPRECATED **
//
```

Seems just that the information hasn't made its' way to the official MSDN doc of [MAKELANGID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-makelangid) yet.

Even if it did work correctly, it's the worse option since it tries to find the error string on that specified LangID and only that one ID, failing if it doesn't exist. Using 0 instead will very likely return at least *something*, even if that error isn't localized to the user's language.

Quote from MSDN [FormatMessageW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessagew):

> [in] dwLanguageId
>
> The language identifier for the requested message. This parameter is ignored if dwFlags includes FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING.
>
> If you pass a specific LANGID in this parameter, FormatMessage will return a message for that LANGID only. If the function cannot find a message for that LANGID, it sets Last-Error to ERROR_RESOURCE_LANG_NOT_FOUND. If you pass in zero, FormatMessage looks for a message for LANGIDs in the following order:
>
> 1. Language neutral
> 2. Thread LANGID, based on the thread's locale value
> 3. User default LANGID, based on the user's default locale value
> 4. System default LANGID, based on the system default locale value
> 5. US English
>
> If FormatMessage does not locate a message for any of the preceding LANGIDs, it returns any language message string that is present. If that fails, it returns ERROR_RESOURCE_LANG_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: This implementation leaks memory in case the `String` c'tor throws an exception. It also needlessly calculates the string length after knowing the length already. Compare to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329) implementation that addresses both issues.

Comment: Also, returning by `const` value does more harm than good (if any). You have just disabled the compiler's ability to move from this value, forcing clients to make unnecessary copies. Honestly, the more I look at this the more I feel like this is actually down-vote material. Sorry.