# get a text from the error code returns from the GetLastError() function

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

I need to get the text of an error code that i got from the GetLastError function.
I saw a few examples but i want a function that get the code and return the string.
Thank's you all

Comment: "GetLastError" is not standard C++.  Are you using Win32 or some other API from which the GetLastError function comes?

Comment: Should this be tagged as 'winapi'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the error message from the error code returned by GetLastError()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror)

Answer (score 46):

I guess you want something like this:

```
DWORD   dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
TCHAR   lpBuffer[256] = _T("?");
if(dwLastError != 0)    // Don't want to see a "operation done successfully" error ;-)
    ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,                 // It´s a system error
                     NULL,                                      // No string to be formatted needed
                     dwLastError,                               // Hey Windows: Please explain this error!
                     MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),  // Do it in the standard language
                     lpBuffer,              // Put the message here
                     STR_ELEMS(lpBuffer)-1,                     // Number of bytes to store the message
                     NULL);
```

Also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Mind setting this to answered then? Thanks!

Comment: You *really* have to lose that static_cast, that just generates Chinese or one letter messages.

Comment: Actually, it works just fine. I copied this from one of our projects. But don't ask me why someone put the cast in there... I removed it.

Comment: On compiling, i have an error: `'FormatMessageW': function does not accept arguments 6`. Curiously, i'm using `FormatMessage` and **not** `FormatMessageW`

Comment: I'm afraid, there are too many issues with this implementation. See the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387064/1889329) for more information.

Comment: i got **STR_ELEMS** is `undefined` so i removed it but still it worked i printed lpBuffer.