# C++: Deleting a printer queue

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, error-handling

I'm trying to remove all the files in queue from a printer. I found [this piece of code](http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=370&ver=vcpp) which seemed pretty straight forward.

I tried deleting the queue with the code below. It compiles, but SetPrinter returns false. The error message I got was 5, which I tried to decode to a "normal" error message using the approach [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006229/get-a-text-from-the-error-code-returns-from-the-getlasterror-function). But I wasn't able to compile with that, because STR_ELEMS is undefined. Searched google for "STR_ELEMS is undefined" but hit a dead end.

Can someone help me decode the error message and delete the printer queue?

```
BOOL bStatus = false;
HANDLE     hPrinter = NULL;
DOC_INFO_1 DocInfo;

bStatus = OpenPrinter((LPTSTR)_T("CN551A"), &hPrinter, NULL);

if(bStatus) {

    DWORD dwBufsize=0;

    GetPrinterA(hPrinter, 2, NULL, 0, &dwBufsize); // Edit: Returns false

    PRINTER_INFO_2* pinfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)malloc(dwBufsize);
    long result = GetPrinterA(hPrinter, 2, 
        (LPBYTE)pinfo, dwBufsize, &dwBufsize);

    if ( pinfo->cJobs==0 ) // Edit: pinfo->cJobs is not 0
    {
        printf("No printer jobs found.");
    }
    else
    {
        if ( SetPrinter(hPrinter, 0, 0, PRINTER_CONTROL_PURGE)==0 )
            printf("SetPrinter call failed: %x\n", GetLastError() );
        else printf("Number of printer jobs deleted: %u\n",
            pinfo->cJobs);
    }

    ClosePrinter( hPrinter );

}
```

My includes are:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winspool.h>
```

Comment: What does `GetPrinter` return? It's supposed to be a `BOOL`, and `0` indicates failure.

Comment: It returns false actually. Didn't check that one. So am i defining the hPrinter handle wrong in some way?

Comment: What's the value of `dwBufsize`? BTW, there's no reason to `malloc` the `PRINTER_INFO_2` structure. Just declare it as a non-pointer and pass it's address to `GetPrinter` like `(LPBYTE)&pinfo`.

Comment: If i change it to PRINTER_INFO2 pinfo, and then retreive the address &pinfo, like you suggested, then there is not enough available memory i think (i'm getting an exception error). If i cout dwBufSize i get 3080, which i'm guessing is the number of bytes of pinfo?

Comment: You're right about `PRINTER_INFO_2`. But there are two calls to `GetPrinter`. Print out the return value and the value of `dwBufsize` after both calls.

Comment: The first call to GetPrinter returns false with dwBufsize 3080, and the second call returns true with dwBufsize 3080. Does this makes sense?

Comment: I think it makes sense since the first call was only to initialize `dwBufsize`. So I'd say that `GetPrinter` is succeeding and the problem is definitely with the `SetPrinter` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code of 5 means "access is denied". ([System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Try running with admin privileges.

To format a printable error message from the return value of `GetLastError`, use `FormatMessage` something like this:

```
  TCHAR buffer[256];
  if (0 == FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0,
           GetLastError(), 0, buffer, 256, 0)) {
    // FormatMessage failed.
  }
```

Also, you can try passing a `PRINTER_DEFAULTS` struct to `OpenPrinter`, maybe like this:

```
PRINTER_DEFAULTS PrnDefs;
PrnDefs.pDataType = "RAW";
PrnDefs.pDevMode = 0;
PrnDefs.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS;

bStatus = OpenPrinter((LPTSTR)_T("CN551A"), &hPrinter, &PrnDefs);
```

Comment: Thank you. I opened the project in administrator mode. Unfortunately SetPrinter still return false. If i output the value of buffer (cout << *buffer<<endl;) i get 65?

Comment: Print `buffer` (the whole string), not `*buffer` (the first character).

Comment: I tried that at first, but got the output: 00E2FA48 (memory address?)

Comment: Got it! std::wcout << L"Error: " << buffer << '\n'; outputs: Access is denied

Comment: I'm not sure what a project's "administrator mode" is. Have you tried logging in to your operating system as the admin? And what OS are you on?

Comment: Just tried another printer, but with same result. I'm using Windows 8. Some permissions are pretty strict so that might be an issue. I am logged in as administrator. I'm gonna shift-restart and see if i can find something that might be an issue.

Comment: What's the value of `pinfo->pSecurityDescriptor`? Not it's exact value, but is it `0` or not.

Comment: Try the idea about `PRINTER_DEFAULTS` that I added to my answer above.

Comment: IT WORKS! I had to cast "RAW": (LPWSTR)_T("RAW"), but then it did the job! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an explanation as to why it works? Is the printername "CN551A" just a nickname, and the system needs more information?

Comment: I guess you opened it with no access rights, or at least not enough to purge the queue. So you had to set that last parameter to the type of access you wanted.