# How to Cancel/Reset page between StartPage/EndPage when printing?

Tags: c, winapi, printing

I'm processing a specially formatted text file to send to the printer.  I have encountered a condition that would be easiest to handle by discarding the current (incomplete) page and starting a new one instead.  So, I have called StartPage() and output one or more lines of output and then I realize that I need to discard what I have output *on this page only* before I have called EndPage().  To me, this seems like it should be a simple and obvious function, but I have been unable to find any way to do this.  Is it possible or am I just dreaming?

EDIT:  In case this wasn't clear, I want to remove a single, partially completed page from my output and then continue to output additional pages.  I DO NOT want to remove the entire job (or print queue.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Deleting a printer queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825373/c-deleting-a-printer-queue)

Comment: Why don't you structure your code so that you don't print anything until you are sure you want to?

Comment: I'm working on that, but I would like to learn if this obvious (to me, at least) function is possible and if so, how to do it.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this function would exist. Generally you need to program to the interface.

Comment: I searched for a while and didn't find the API you needed. I think before the Endpage, you can print the content correctly and call it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what I want does not exist.

I have assumed that between StartPage() and EndPage(), my printer output for the page is being buffered to build an image of the page to send to the printer.  Apparently I can neither (a) change my mind and discard the incomplete (or completed) page nor (b) change (or remove) what I have already written to the page.  I tried (b) and I got two lines of text superimposed upon one another.