# Allocate memory in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [malloc() vs. HeapAlloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224347/malloc-vs-heapalloc)

I know we can use `malloc`/`free` in C to allocate/release heap memory, and use `new`/`delete` in C++ to do the similar things.

As for Windows, I occasionally saw people use `HeapAlloc` etc APIs to allocate memory, which are the differences from the C/C++ counterparts?

And which is the best way to allocate a `wchar_t` buffer on heap which will be used as input for some Windows APIs?

Comment: If you have to ask, don't use `HeapAlloc`. You're not the audience for that function.

Comment: The best way is most likely a `std::wstring` or `std::vector<wchar_t>`.

Answer (score 1):

malloc/new are implemented using HeapAlloc, so there is very little practical difference. There are of course the implementation differences; malloc will return null on failure, new will throw, etc.