# Memory corruption with GetProcessHeap/HeapAlloc

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, dll

As a learning/testing-my-limits exercise, I'm trying to make a DLL that can take a given value, serialize it, and de-serialize it *for a program compiled with another compiler*. So far everything's gone better than expected. However, I'm running into what appears to be a memory corruption issue.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
//POD_base.h: contains the base template POD (plain old data) class. Also contains memory allocation and deallocation functions.
namespace pod_helpers
{
  void* pod_malloc(size_t size)
  {
    HANDLE heapHandle = GetProcessHeap();
    HANDLE storageHandle = nullptr;

    if (heapHandle == nullptr)
    {
      return nullptr;
    }

    storageHandle = HeapAlloc(heapHandle, 0, size);

    return storageHandle;
  }

  void pod_free(void* ptr)
  {
    HANDLE heapHandle = GetProcessHeap();
    if (heapHandle == nullptr)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (ptr == nullptr)
    {
      return;
    }

    HeapFree(heapHandle, 0, ptr);
  }
}

template<typename T>
class pod
{
protected:
  pod();
  pod(const T& value);
  pod(const pod& copy);                   // no copy ctor in any pod
  ~pod();

  pod<T>& operator=(pod<T> value);
  operator T() const;

  T get() const;
  void swap(pod<T>& first, pod<T>& second);
};
```

A `pod` specialization for `int`:

```
//POD_basic_types.h: contains pod specializations for basic datatypes
template<>
class pod<int>
{
  typedef int original_type; //these typedefs are meant to make the specializations easier to write and understand, since they're all the same except for the underlying datatypes.
  typedef std::int32_t safe_type;

public:
  pod() : data(nullptr) {}

  pod(const original_type& value)
  {
    set_from(value);
  }

  pod(const pod<original_type>& copyVal)
  {
    original_type copyData = copyVal.get();
    set_from(copyData);
  }

  ~pod()
  {
    release();
  }

  pod<original_type>& operator=(pod<original_type> value)
  {
    swap(*this, value);

    return *this;
  }

  operator original_type() const
  {
    return get();
  }

protected:
  safe_type* data;

  original_type get() const
  {
    original_type result;

    result = static_cast<original_type>(*data);

    return result;
  }

  void set_from(const original_type& value)
  {
    data = reinterpret_cast<safe_type*>(pod_helpers::pod_malloc(sizeof(safe_type)));

    if (data == nullptr)
    {
      return;
    }

    new(data) safe_type (value);
  }

  void release()
  {
    if (data)
    {
      pod_helpers::pod_free(data);
      data = nullptr;
    }
  }

  void swap(pod<original_type>& first, pod<original_type>& second)
  {
    using std::swap;

    swap(first.data, second.data);
  }
};
```

My DLL takes advantage of this behind-the-scenes type conversion like this:

```
virtual pod<int> Add(const pod<int> number1, const pod<int> number2);

pod<int> CCDLL_v1_implementation::Add(const pod<int> number1, const pod<int> number2)
{
  int workingNum1, workingNum2;

  workingNum1 = number1;
  workingNum2 = number2;

  return workingNum1 + workingNum2;
}
```

Then my test program loads the DLL via `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`. So far, so good; I've confirmed that the DLL is actually loaded and the `Add` function called. I've also verified that `pod<int>`'s `set_from` is being called with the correct values. However, this is where things break down.

I expect `set_from` to allocate enough space for one `safe_type` (in this case, `std::int32_t`) value, then store the passed value within the allocated memory. When I check the value of `*data` within `set_from`, this seems to be the case. However, when I'm retrieving the `pod<int>`'s value via `get`, the pod's `data` appears to be garbage. It no longer points to the value the `pod` was passed during `set_from`.

I know `set_from` is called on the EXE's side and `get` is called on the DLL's side. My understanding of the process is as follows:

```
EXE -> creates pod<int> (allocating memory via GetProcessHeap/HeapAlloc) -> constructs the pod with a given value, which is passed to set_from.
The DLL's Add function is called, with the given pod passed to it.
DLL -> accesses pod<int> -> gets the pod's stored value via get -> accesses the memory the EXE allocated
DLL does its calculations (here, a simple addition) with the pod's value
DLL -> creates pod<int> (allocating memory via GetProcessHeap/HeapAlloc) -> constructs the pod with a given value, which is passed to set_from.
The DLL's newly-constructed pod is returned to the EXE.
EXE -> accesses the pod's internal value via get -> accesses the memory the DLL allocated
```

This seems to be breaking down where either the DLL or the EXE has to access memory the other allocated. I've seen [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224347/malloc-vs-heapalloc/8722008#8722008) that using this combination of `GetProcessHeap`/`HeapAlloc` *should* work across DLL boundaries. [`HeapCreate`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx) is also suggestive of the same idea:

> The memory of a private heap object is accessible only to the process that created it. If a dynamic-link library (DLL) creates a private heap, the heap is created in the address space of the process that calls the DLL, and it is accessible only to that process.

as is [the documentation for `GetProcessHeap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The GetProcessHeap function obtains a handle to the default heap **for the calling process**.

Oddly enough, however, [`GlobalAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574(v=vs.85).aspx) suffered the same problems `GetProcessHeap`/`HeapAlloc` did, making me further question what's going wrong here. Even odder, when I compile both the EXE and the DLL with the same compiler, everything works as expected.

Am I making incorrect assumptions about the way this allocation/deallocation process works? Should I be using something other than `GetProcessHeap`/`HeapAlloc`? Or am I simply trying to do the impossible?

---

Update with information gained from the comments:

Passing a `pod` by reference (`CCDLL_v1_implementation::Add(const pod<int>& number1, const pod<int>& number2)` works correctly. Only passing by value does not.

It doesn't appear to matter whether I pass "unwrapped" arguments to a `pod`-taking function or whether I wrap the arguments in `pod`s first:

```
pod<int> a = 9;
pod<int> b = 2;

CCDLL_lib->Add(a, b);
```

produces the same corrupted `data` as

```
CCDLL_lib->Add(9, 2);
```

The only difference seems to be that wrapping arguments in `pod`s first will call the copy c'tor when `Add` is called, and leaving arguments unwrapped will just call the regular c'tor.

This also doesn't seem to be a class layout issue:

```
if (reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&data) == reinterpret_cast<const void*>(this))
{
  //simple debug messagebox here
}
```

evaluates to true on both sides of the EXE/DLL boundary.

---

I've managed to prove the issue lies on the EXE/DLL boundary, although I still don't know why.

I added a new method to the DLL so I could focus on one argument instead of two:

```
void Square(pod<int> number);
```

Then I called it like this:

```
pod<int> a = 9;
CCDLL_lib->Square(a);
```

From a series of debug messageboxes, the following sequence occurs:

```
Regular c'tor called (EXE)
set_from(9) called (EXE)
copy c'tor called (EXE)
get returns 9 to the copy c'tor (EXE)
set_from(9) called (EXE)
Square called (DLL) with an invalid pod (Visual Studio shows the data pointer pointing to garbage at this point)
```

If I change `Square` to accept a reference instead (`virtual void Square(pod<int>& number) = 0;`), the following sequence occurs:

```
Regular c'tor called (EXE)
set_from(9) called (EXE)
Square called (DLL) with a valid pod (Visual Studio shows the data pointer holding correct data)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you're using the heap.  In fact, from your description, things are going wrong before any of the heap allocations are freed?  However: I don't use C++ much, but it looks to me as if some of the code in the `pod` class might be compiled directly into the executable rather than calling the DLL.  If a single `pod` object is being accessed by both the DLLs version and the EXEs version of the code, that would explain your problem.

Comment: @Harry Yep, things are going wrong before any memory is freed. The way problems occur is quite consistent: `set_from` is called, during which `data` has expected values; then `get` is called, during which `data` is corrupted; then `release` is called. Also, I'm actually expecting the EXE and DLL to operate on the same `pod`; the EXE sets up the pod and the DLL pulls it apart, then vice versa. I'm just not sure where `data` goes bad.

Comment: You can't operate on a class object from multiple compilers, because (for a start) there's no standard for the way the members are laid out in memory.  If the EXE writes `data` starting at the fourth byte of the object and the DLL expects it to start at the eighth byte, boom!  That's almost certainly why you're getting the wrong value for `data`; you're not reading it from where it was written.

Comment: @Harry As far as I'm aware, the class's layout should be standard. [The `offsetof` docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) state it works on a standard-layout class, and `std::is_standard_layout` returned true when I tested it on a `pod`.

Comment: Also see my discussion with @deGoot in the comments of [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306541/repackaging-binary-data-in-a-dll-how-does-this-work)

Comment: Do both compilers support C++11?  I'd suggest you double-check whether the layout is actually the same or not: for example, you could create a static `std::int32_t **` and set it to the address of the `data` pointer in set_from(), then in get() you can explicitly compare it to what it thinks the address is.

Comment: If the value of `data` is actually being overwritten, it may be possible to set a data checkpoint in the debugger to locate the point at which it changes.

Comment: @Harry Both compilers support C++11. As of right now, I'm building the DLL with Visual Studio 2013 and the test EXE with GCC 4.8.1. Using the `std::int32 **` test you suggested, `dataCheckPtr == &data` in `set_from`, but `dataCheckPtr != &data` in `get`. But oddly enough `offsetof(pod<int>, data);` returns 0 from both the EXE side and DLL side. This seems self-contradictory, but I'm probably missing something obvious...

Comment: It should be easy to find out on which side (if either) `offsetof` is behaving as expected, just check whether `&data == &pod` or not.  I don't think VS2013 is fully C++11 compatible.  In particular, see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438475.aspx

Comment: @computerfreaker: You're passing `pod<int>` by value to the `Add` function, which will invoke the copy constructor of your `pod`. Maybe passing the data by reference will help (i.e. `virtual pod<int> Add(const pod<int>& number1, const pod<int>& number2);`). Otherwise, the problem may be with the data copy workflow. Also, for the sake of analysis, I suggest you try the approach with an inputs-only function first before trying inputs and outputs to determine where the problem is.

Comment: @Harry `if (reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&data) == reinterpret_cast<const void*>(this))` comes out true no matter where I check it. That's a good sanity check, though, since the contradictory results from the pointer check and the `offsetof` check were making me question everything.

Comment: @deGoot _Maybe passing the data by reference will help_ That's actually it. Wow. I adjusted my method signature as you suggested and the method gets inputs successfully now. Apparently my copy c'tor needs some love. (This is also confirmed by the method getting *inputs* successfully when passed by reference, but crashing when trying to *return* a `pod` value.)

Comment: And now that I'm testing more, the copy c'tor never actually gets called on either side. This gets odder and odder. When passing arguments to `Add`, the regular c'tor (`pod(const original_type& value)`) is called for both arguments, then the `()` operator is called for both arguments, and spits out a bad `data` pointer.

Comment: Keep in mind that (if I've understood correctly) now that you've added a virtual function it is no longer a standard-layout class.

Comment: @Harry Nope, the virtual function is part of the DLL. I left out most of the DLL's structure because it's not relevant to the question, but think of `Square` as a a parallel of `Add`. I'll edit my question again to clear that up (edit: done). The `pod` class hasn't changed, I just wanted an extra test method in the DLL so I could focus entirely on one input parameter instead of two inputs and an output.

Comment: Is the binary protocol for passing a class object by value standardized?  To be honest at this point I don't think you're going to work out what's happening without stepping through the assembly code for `CCDLL_lib->Square(a)`.

Comment: @Harry I'm not sure if there's a _standard_ protocol for passing a class object by value, but attempting to logic it out seems sound enough. `&data == &pod<int>`, so there's no debug information at the start of the class. `#pragma pack(push, 1)` guarantees no extra padding in the class. And the class is standard-layout, so the class is always laid out the same way. Therefore, the class is fixed in size and all class members (should just be `data` anyway) are fixed in position. The only abnormality I could see would be `&pod` being incorrectly placed; I'll have to check the asm as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, at this point I'd hazard a guess that the object is being read from the wrong address.  (You could confirm by getting the constructor to report the value of `this` and Square to report the value of `&number`.)  Another thought: if this is 64-bit code, by any chance does the problem go away if you have more than one pointer stored in `pod` objects?

Comment: @Harry Your guess seems to be correct. I'm still working on figuring out exactly how far off the class pointer ends up, but `this` in the copy c'tor and `&number` in `Square` are definitely different. I guess it's time to try and figure out some asm. And while this is 32-bit code, a second pointer does in fact come out with the correct value. (The `dataCheckPtr` I used for checking `data`'s consistency earlier pointed to the correct location of `data` even after `data` itself was corrupted.)