# Retrieve array member from struct in separate function

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm having trouble with retrieving some values from a struct. In the below simplified snippets, struct Model's vertices member contains an array of values that can be retrieved correctly if buildModel() is called with drawModel() called within it. However, if I call buildModel() and then drawModel() afterwards, there are no errors, but the vertices are not retrieved with the correct values. This leads me to believe either a variable scope ended, I am passing the references incorrectly, or the vertices member needs to be defined on the heap with malloc.

MODEL.H:

```
typedef struct Model{
   Vertex *vertices;
} Model;

Model* newModel();

Model* setVertices(Vertex *vertices, Model *model);
```

MODEL.CPP:

```
Model* newModel(){
   Model* model;
   model = (Model* )malloc(sizeof(Model));
   //model->vertices = (Vertex *)malloc(sizeof(Vertex)); This did not help...

   return model;
}

Model* setVertices(Vertex *vertices, Model *model){
   model->vertices = vertices;

   return model;
}
```

DRAWING.CPP:

```
Model* buildModel(){
   Model* model = newModel();

   Vertex vertices[] = {
      { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 5.0f, -1.0f), (XMFLOAT4)colorX},
      ...  //Abbreviated declaration
   };

   model = setVertices(vertices, model);

   //drawModel(model);    Calling drawModel() here retrieves vertices correctly

   return model;
}

void drawModel(Model *model){
   loadVertices(d3dDeviceRef, 11, model->vertices); //Trying to pass vertices array here
}
```

This has been very useful in learning, and am trying to use as few classes as possible and go more the C route than C++ when I can.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to "go the C route", use C, not C++. Otherwise use the features a language provides. Anyway, this is C++, so do not use C tag. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: And there is no array member shown. A pointer is not an array and vice-versa!

Comment: @Olaf Will try using C again soon, Visual Studio was preventing me from using it based on some of the libraries I was working with. In the meantime, it seems some C solutions can also work in C++. Like David Heffernan's answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224387/1914293) said `malloc` could be used in C++ but `new` is expected. Totally agree about taking a language seriously, still learning though, even from your comments.

Comment: **Do not compile C code with a C++ compiler!** C has evolved a lot, as has C++. Note that C means at least C99, but actually standard C, which is **only** C11 (there are no multiple C standards). Even for identical syntax&grammar some semantics differ subtle, but significantly. The common subset of both languages is too small to write good non-trivial code in any language. A generalised personal note: I would refuse any code from a student or co-worker which sacrifices language features which enhance code-quality for the sake of compatibility.

Comment: @Olaf Semi-compatible code is a bad idea, but have had intention of re-writing with what I learned one day. Instead of just using the above for personal use, keeping co-workers or a teacher in perspective as a user is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vertices` array is local to the `buildModel`function. As soon as the function returns, the array is gone.

This is equivalent to [returning a pointer to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable), just a bit more complicated.

I would recommend the C++ way, and use a `std::vector` instead of a bunch of pointers.

Comment: The vertices array going away makes sense. So I'll try using std::vector for the model and see if the vertices are kept intact. Will also try declaring vertices on the heap properly as in the "returning a pointer to a local variable" link you included. Appreciated

Comment: Keeping track of the pointers here through debugging their addresses. A lot of language concepts to iron out, but thanks for pointing out the scope problem. Separated the funcs for this work in progress, need to buy a book eventually so I stop unlearning malloc, memcpy, addressing principles. I dislike how I declared the vertices array, so will eventually read from file.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add to your `struct Model` an `int` to store the number of vertices and to take it into consideration across the rest of the program:

```
typedef struct Model{
   Vertex *vertices;
   int nVertices; // add this
} Model;
```

then you have to allocate in `newModel()` the memory for it like this:

```
model = (Model* )malloc(nVertices*sizeof(Vertex)+sizeof(int)); // this will allocate the necessary space
```

(at that point, the number of vertices must be defined)

then use `memset()` to set to zero the allocated memory (if you need)
then add to `setVertices();` a new `int` parameter to send the number of vertices and set the `model->nVertices` with it.

Comment: The malloc style you used cleared up some sizing questions I had in the back of my head. Thanks.

Comment: Got it running now. Not sure the best practice here, but going to stick with malloc'ing sizeof(Model) and malloc its members separately. Then I could use the Model, let its members be pointers, and malloc its vertices from other functions. This helped, so marking this answer 'up.'