# Win32 API: GetLastError() with FormatMessage() prints a junk

Tags: c++, winapi, character-encoding, mingw, wine

I'm just trying to get a text of the last error with this simple code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    char err[256];
    memset(err, 0, 256);
    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
                   MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), err, 255, NULL);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", err); // just for the safe case
    puts(err);
    return 0;
}
```

`FormatMessage()` tries probably to write something like `No error`, but instead I getting: `┬√яюыэхэю єёях°эю` in *WINE*, and `╬яхЁрЎш  єёях°эю чртхЁ°хэр` under *WinXP* in *VirtualBox*.

I checked every idea I've had: 1) [in an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386923/2388257), for some reason, a `wchar_t` is used, so I tried creating a buffer of `wchar_t`s, and casting it for `FormatMessage` *(otherwise build fails with `cannot convert ‘wchar_t*’ to ‘LPSTR {aka char*}’ for argument ‘5’`)*, 2) then I thought, perhaps encoding differs from the GNU/Linux one, so I installed WinXP into VirtualBox; but none of two functions gave anything readable, app keeps mumbling its own weird language.

*OS: Ubuntu(WINE), WinXP(VirtualBox). Compiler: MinGW GCC*

**UPD**: I found a working code!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    wchar_t err[256];
    memset(err, 0, 256);
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
                  MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), err, 255, NULL);
    int msgboxID = MessageBoxW( NULL,
                                err,
                                (LPCWSTR)L"☠",
                                MB_OK );
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiled with the `-mwindows` flag, it shows up a message box with readable text in both Ubuntu and WinXP. So, the problem looks to be terminal-only.

Comment: This could be an encoding mismatch, what does the output of `chcp` give you?

Comment: @user657267 in the WinXP it gave `current code page: 866`.

Comment: Call `SetLastError` with a system error value first to make your code predictable. I don't think there's any guarantee that the "first last error" is anything in particular, or even something that makes sense.

Comment: @Hi-Angel And what is your windows system language?

Comment: @molbdnilo Executed on native windows, it's a pleasant surprise to get the message "The operation succeeded", when there was no last error.

Comment: @Christophe does you executed just my code?

Comment: @user657267 I am not sure where to look exactly, but seems that this is Russian.

Comment: @Hi-Angel can you give me the Russian for "The operation succeeded"? You might want to try using `chcp` to switch codepages just in case, try the ones labelled as [russian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx), e.g. `chcp 855` and run your program again.

Comment: @Hi-Angel,  yes your code, but with TCHAR as described below and the puts() commented out.  You can find the exact message  here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Christophe, I am just asked my colleague to compile my code with your additions, and also unicode version proposed by Edward Clements with `FormatMessageW()`. The first one printed a bunch of question signs, the second printed nothing. He is running Win8 and MS VS2013.

Comment: Ok !  The bunch of question sign, is what I obtain when I compile the code without the _UNICODE and UNICODE #defines that I mentioned in the comment to my answer.

Comment: @Christophe alas: I didn't removed this `define`s when I compiled the code in MS VS. And the question signs was anyway... Btw, the compiler wrote some warnings about those `define`s. I also thought that may be the problem is in Win8, and copied an executables to my WinXP, but the WinXP said that some dll wasn't found. So we tried to find in MS VS an option for static linking, but without success.

Comment: @Christophe I just looked: the warnings is about macro redefinition. If comment out those `define`s, the output of application doesn't changed even a bit.

Comment: @user657267 sorry, I mislooked your comment. I was tried to switch to 437 USA, but the output is just another nonsense. The "operation succeed" would sound in russian like "Операция удалась".

Comment: This is pretty bizarre. Your code works perfectly well.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Given that the text you posted in your question is exclusively in the 0x80-0xFF range for page 866 this is almost certainly a terminal code page issue, look at the page I linked above for Cyrillic and Russian code pages and try each one with `chcp`, running your app again each time.

Comment: There is no reasonable scenario in which you can call [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) without the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag.

Comment: @IInspectable why? Do Windows errors uses in some cases such a sequences?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: If you browse through [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx) you will find several messages that contain placeholders (e.g. `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`: *"%1 is not a valid Win32 application."*). The system does not provide an interface to query the number and data types of placeholders, which makes them essentially useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminal is set to the wrong code page, the sequence ┬√яюыэхэю in code page 866 is Выполнено in code page 1251 (i.e. the raw bytes `c2 fb ef ee eb ed e5 ed ee`), change your terminal code page by calling

```
chcp 1251
```

before you run your app and try again.

As to why your terminal code page does not match your system code page is anyone's guess, try resetting the cmd.exe settings for the local user by deleting the HKCU\Console registry key (make a registry backup first just in case).

Comment: Well, you're right. So, in order to make a program work in the *WINE* I need to launch like this `LANG=ru_RU.cp1251 wine a.exe` *(where a.exe is an application to be launched)* Unfortunately this did not a trick in Windows; anyway, I think that I can accept the answer, as this is proves that if user of an application can't see an output, he is just have wrong encoding. And either way, the terminal output I am was needed only for debug, in the release I will use GUI, of course. And, as I shown in the update, the GUI works just fine with encoding.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Right, I forgot you were using wine, anyway all's well that ends well! For future reference you might want to consider defining the UNICODE macro and using wide strings to avoid this altogether.

Comment: user657267, the unicode with `wchar_t`s doesn't worked in terminal either ;)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are mixing Unicode and multi-byte character sets, your code should be something like the following

```
int main() // unicode
{   wchar_t err[256];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
                  MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), err, 255, NULL);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", err);//just for the safe case
    _putws(err);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: added MBCS version

```
int main() // MBCS
{   char err[256];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
                  MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), err, 255, NULL);
    printf("%s\n", err);//just for the safe case
    puts(err);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I copied all your code(just added a cast), but the output is still the same :( *Note*: your code doesn't compiled, as you missing a cast for argument 5, I am mentioned alike situation in my post.

Comment: adding cast is not the correct way to go -- is your project Unicode or MBCS?

Comment: I am had wrote a comment, but just catched a flashed thought: what does your question meant? Could it meant that under a Windows for the Unicode I need to add some flag for the time of compilation? And yes, I'd wanted a Unicode.

Comment: I'm not very sure about other environments, but in Windows (Visual Studio), there's a setting "Character Set", I would recommend setting it to "Use Unicode Character Set"; there may be equivalent settings for other O/S-es and compilers

Comment: MBCS version prints a junk too; anyway, [here's interesting comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281819/win32-api-getlasterror-with-formatmessage-prints-a-junk/25282308#comment39398962_25281819) from @Christophe. I think I need to ask my colleague to compile this code in MS VS to see what it does...

Comment: I personally prefer not to use the *A and *W variants and let the compiler decide which one to use depending on the Character Set selected for the project -- Visual Studio definitely has one in Project-PropertyPages\Configuration Properties\General

Comment: I think I need to answer your last comment: this is definitely an IDE feature(not even the compiler), and it is surely bad idea to depend on this. On the internet is a bunch of an IDE's and as result your code just wouldn't compile in someone's hands.

Comment: IDEs are just a convenient way to do things, when you check "Use Unicode Character Set" in Visual Studio IDE, it compiles all sources with "_UNICODE" and "UNICODE" #defined

Comment: Okay. But does this changed my last comment? Your code still won't work because it is the IDE who sets those `define`s, not you.

Comment: actually no, the IDE just creates a project file (.vcxproj), the command-line to compile the source is in there (`/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\www.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue`); when I run the code, I get "The operation completed successfully" on my console.

Comment: Don't follow the code-by-coincidence idiom. If you pass a `char` array, call `FormatMessageA`. If you go with a `wchar_t` array, use `FormatMessageW` instead. If you call `FormatMessage`, always pass a `TCHAR` array. Don't get those mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

You have to adapt your coding to the windows API.

With native windows compiler,  the err is immediatly spotted out as wrong type

Declare:

```
TCHAR err[256];
```

TCHAR is #defined to be consistent with all other functions declared in windows.h.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  explains the principle behind this microsoft specific naming convention.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can also see that there are two versions of FormatMessage(): FormatMessageW (Unicode strings i.e. wchar_t) and FormatMessageA (ANSI i.e. char).

**Edit:**
In the case of cross compilation, perticular care should be taken about `#defines`, that are generated automatically in the case of native use of MSVC.  So don't forget to define the following symbols before including windows.h:  WIN32, _CONSOLE, _UNICODE and UNICODE.

Comment: Alas, it didn't changed the output.

Comment: Hhm... And if you `#define WIN32`, `#define _CONSOLE` and `#define _UNICODE` and `#define UNICODE` at the beginning of your file, before including windows.h ?  There are predefined settings on my native windows compiler.

Comment: Hm... I just found that with the @EdwardClements's code (but with the `FormatMessageW()` the function `_putws(err)` prints nothing(but it prints `K?>;=5=> CA?5H=>.` under wine). What should be printed when no error?

Comment: The message is language specific, but its something like "The operation succeded".  By the way, did you try with the additional #defines above ?

Comment: yes, these defines doesn't changed an output. Tried with both the versions of function that I have so far.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a simple console output problem ?  The windows console is not unicode, and some non ascii unicode chars are then simply presented as garbage.  In french for example, all 'é'  are always presented as 'ù'.  That's not a bug, that's the console design.  In fact if you want to see pure unicode output, you'll have create a real windows program writing output text in a window with GDI functions

Comment: But I said in one of the comments that you had tried just my code, so this was a console output, isn't it? And all worked... Something strange going on... Hm.

Comment: Yes, but I have a french version of windows, so 95% of the chars are ok,  and I don't interpret the one accented char as "garbage", but a known formt issue due to the unicode.