# Should I set the Arguments parameter when using FormatMessage to retrieve Windows API error messages?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, error-handling

I am attempting to get the error message that relates to the `GetLastError` Windows API function.

I have followed the examples given here relating to the `FormatMessage` function:

[How to get the error message from the error code returned by GetLastError()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror?rq=1)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

My implementation is returning a string but noticed through testing that some error messages are including text such as "%1".  For example, for the error code 574:

> {Application Error} The exception %s (0x%08lx) occurred in the application at location 0x%08lx.

I assume that this is resolved by setting the `Arguments` parameter in the `FormatMessage` function. However, I cannot find a suitable tutorial/example for setting this parameter on system error messages.  The links I have provided set this parameter to `NULL`.

Is this because ANY Windows API call that sets the last error message via `SetLastError` never uses a code that corresponds to a message that uses the `Arguments` parameter?

Otherwise, how do I create such a `va_list` for system error messages?

Comment: How can you know what args to pass?

Comment: I recalled incorrectly, it's really a va-list. Checking now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I don't, which is obviously the problem if I want to reliably dump a failed Windows API message to screen or a log file visible to a client, let alone something our support team can use to investigate a problem. This is only a problem with failed Windows API calls that use messages requiring arguments.

Comment: @rasteve: the arguments are not *required*. they can just be omitted. it's not at all unusual to dump messages with insert specifications still there.

Comment: @rasteve: In order to supply arguments you need to special-case all the relevant messages. That means you can simply substitute your own messages.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - This is my main worry, having to consider both functional AND message concerns in a generic wrapper that respects the thread's `langid`. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this **should ideally be a comment** except for the by-design lack of support for technical comments here on SO. So, I'll gladly delete this shortly. But, for now, info: Microsoft's headers contain the following informative comment:

```
//====== ShellMessageBox ================================================

// If lpcTitle is NULL, the title is taken from hWnd
// If lpcText is NULL, this is assumed to be an Out Of Memory message
// If the selector of lpcTitle or lpcText is NULL, the offset should be a
//     string resource ID
// The variable arguments must all be 32-bit values (even if fewer bits
//     are actually used)
// lpcText (or whatever string resource it causes to be loaded) should
//     be a formatting string similar to wsprintf except that only the
//     following formats are available:
//         %%              formats to a single '%'
//         %nn%s           the nn-th arg is a string which is inserted
//         %nn%ld          the nn-th arg is a DWORD, and formatted decimal
//         %nn%lx          the nn-th arg is a DWORD, and formatted hex
//     note that lengths are allowed on the %s, %ld, and %lx, just
//                         like wsprintf
//
```

I would not be surprised if this applies to `FormatMessage`.

Also, I would check documentation around the message compiler and message resources.

Also note from the documentation of `FormatMessage`,

> **”** If you do not have a pointer of type `va_list*`, then specify the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY` flag and pass a pointer to an array of `DWORD_PTR` values; those values are input to the message formatted as the insert values. Each insert must have a corresponding element in the array.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to "blindly" pass on such error messages that occur in the Windows API functions.  Sounds like I will be overloading our `getMessage` method.