# Error 57 - what does it mean?

Tags: c++

Does anyone know what error code 57 means? I looked on google but it tells me that it is an error with the network card - I'm not sure how that is possible. I get the error when running this function:

```
if (CryptVerifySignature(
    hHash,
    signatureContents,
    dwSigLen,
    phKey,
    NULL,
    0))
{
    printf("The signature has been verified.\n");
}
else
{
    MyHandleError("Error during CryptVerifySignature.");
}
```

MyHandleError

```
void MyHandleError(char *s)
{
fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred in running the program. \n");
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
fprintf(stderr, "Error number %x.\n", GetLastError());
fprintf(stderr, "Program terminating. \n");
exit(1);
```

}

Comment: Look in the MSDN at error codes under CryptVerifySignature.

Comment: What does the [error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064) say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are receiving is actually 87 which means "The parameter is incorrect."

You get 57 because you print it as a hex value (%x and not %d).
57(16) = 87(10)

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):
`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
One of the parameters contains a value that is not valid. This is most often a pointer that is not valid.`