# my python debugger faces an error

Tags: python, debugging

im trying to run a source-code of a primitive debugger in python
but im facing a error and i dont know why is that.you can have the source code down here. 
thank you in advance.

my_debugger_defines.py

```
from ctypes import *
# Let's map the Microsoft types to ctypes for clarity
WORD = c_ushort
DWORD = c_ulong
LPBYTE = POINTER(c_ubyte)
LPTSTR = POINTER(c_char)
HANDLE = c_void_p
# Constants
DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010
# Structures for CreateProcessA() function
class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("cb", DWORD),
    ("lpReserved", LPTSTR),
    ("lpDesktop", LPTSTR),
    ("lpTitle", LPTSTR),
    ("dwX", DWORD),
    ("dwY", DWORD),
    ("dwXSize", DWORD),
    ("dwYSize", DWORD),
    ("dwXCountChars", DWORD),
    ("dwYCountChars", DWORD),
    ("dwFillAttribute",DWORD),
    ("dwFlags", DWORD),
    ("wShowWindow", WORD),
    ("cbReserved2", WORD),
    ("lpReserved2", LPBYTE),
    ("hStdInput", HANDLE),
    ("hStdOutput", HANDLE),
    ("hStdError", HANDLE),
    ]
class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("hProcess", HANDLE),
    ("hThread", HANDLE),
    ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
    ("dwThreadId", DWORD),
    ]
```

my_debugger.py

```
from ctypes import *
from my_debugger_defines import *
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
class debugger():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def load(self,path_to_exe):
        # dwCreation flag determines how to create the process
        # set creation_flags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE if you want
        # to see the calculator GUI
        creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
        # instantiate the structs
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
        # The following two options allow the started process
        # to be shown as a separate window. This also illustrates
        # how different settings in the STARTUPINFO struct can affect
        # the debuggee.
        startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0
        # We then initialize the cb variable in the STARTUPINFO struct
        # which is just the size of the struct itself
        startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
        if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        creation_flags,
        None,
        None,
        byref(startupinfo),
        byref(process_information)):
            print "[*] We have successfully launched the process!"
            print "[*] PID: %d" % process_information.dwProcessId
        else:
            print "[*] Error: {}".format(kernel32.GetLastError())
```

my_test.py

```
import my_debugger
debugger = my_debugger.debugger()
debugger.load("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calcs.exe")
```

running my_test.py in windows console gives me an error of this kind

> [*] Error: 0x00000002

Comment: I'm not ready to love.

Comment: lol no homo actually i have no idea how python-lovers turned to lovers!

Comment: Almost a dup of [How to get the error message from the error code returned by GetLastError()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1387064/2800918)

Comment: This code seems to be [File Not Found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra 's'. Try;

```
debugger.load("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe")
```

Comment: oh damn it! such a rookie mistake:)) thank a lot CAB its working now