# Error using RegisterClassEx

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to learn Win32 through msdn but I am having problems with RegisterClassEx, I checked other threads stating that maybe not all members are initialized but I am sure they are.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static const TCHAR windowclass_sz[] = _T("WindowClass1");
static const TCHAR windowtitle_sz[] = _T("DirectX 12 Demo");

bool Stop = true;


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE PrevhInstance, LPSTR 
lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MSG msg;
HWND hWnd;

WNDCLASSEX wcex;
ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wcex.lpszClassName = windowclass_sz;
wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
{
    GetLastError();
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("RegisterClassEx Call Error!"), _T("ERROR"), 
 MB_ICONERROR && MB_OK );
    return 1;
}

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, windowclass_sz, windowtitle_sz, 
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if (!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx Call Error!"), _T("ERROR"), 
 MB_ICONERROR && MB_OK);
    return 1;
}
else
{
    Stop = false;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

while (Stop == false)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}

return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

As you can see, the RegisterClassEx error is triggered but I have no clue what is wrong.

A message box pops up with "RegisterClassEx Call Error!" and so the program ends there, what is the problem here?

Comment: What is the problem you are noticing?

Comment: Well, the message box refers to WNDCLASSEX so I think that is where I should look, when I couldn't grasp the problem neither by myself nor through other threads I came here.

Comment: Is there a problem?  If so, how do you know there is a problem?  You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: As per your other question, please leave @IInspectable's edit alone - we do not use [Solved] title tags here. Additionally, we prefer commentary about voting not to be added to posts - add a comment if you like, but this material is not of interest to most readers, who do not sign in or vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `RegisterClassEx` **twice** with the same argument. The second call will fail, since the class already exists, and [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) returns error code [1410 (ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385.aspx)<sup>1)</sup>.

Solution: Register any given window class at most once.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *You can convert error codes into human-readable representations by calling [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx). Working sample code is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329).*

Comment: When the 2nd call to `RegisterClassEx()` failed, `GetLastError()` would have told you WHY it failed (but you are ignoring that return value), per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx): "*If the function fails, the return value is zero. **To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`**.*" In this case, the error code returned by `GetLastError()` would be 1410 (`ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS`). To include the system error message in your `MessageBox`, pass the error code to `FormatMessage()` first.