# Why GetMessage function return -1 when hwnd value passed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows

In this code I am drawing line using LineTo function. When I run below code GetMessage function returning -1 value. I am not getting why it is happening. I search At some places it is given that if hwnd is already destroyed then GetMessage function will return -1. When I pass second parameter of GetMessage as NULL My code runs fine. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
long int count_paint =0;
LRESULT CALLBACK my_WindowsProc_1(HWND hwnd, UINT msgkdjaks, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch(msgkdjaks)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
        MoveToEx(hdc,30,30,NULL);
        LineTo(hdc,210,125);
        EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msgkdjaks,w,l);
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hCur, HINSTANCE hPre, LPSTR lpr, int cmd_arg)
{
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd1,hwnd2;
    LPCTSTR class_name=L"My_Window_class";
    int x=0;
    WNDCLASSEX wc1;
    wc1.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc1.style=0;
    wc1.lpfnWndProc=my_WindowsProc_1;
    wc1.cbClsExtra=0;
    wc1.cbWndExtra=0;
    wc1.hInstance=hCur;
    wc1.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc1.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wc1.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc1.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wc1.lpszClassName=class_name;
    wc1.hIconSm=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc1))
    {
        return 10;
    }

    hwnd1 = CreateWindow(class_name, L"This is my window1",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        200,200,300,300,NULL,NULL,hCur,NULL);
    if(hwnd1==NULL)
    {
        return 20;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd1 , cmd_arg);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd1);

    BOOL bRet;
    while((bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hwnd1, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    {
        if (bRet == -1){

            return -20;
        }
        else{
            TranslateMessage(&msg);//
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does GetLastError function says?

Comment: Before while loop GetLastError return 0

Comment: Because before while loop there is no error. You should check last error after GetMessage returned -1 (in if (bRet == -1) {}). See this answer to print last error as string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror

Comment: You get -1 if the hwnd argument is invalid.  It certainly will be invalid after you called DestroyWindow(), GetLastError() will return ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE.  Basic flaw is that the WM_DESTROY handler does not also affect the value of the hwnd1 variable so you continue to use a stale window handle.  You should always use NULL for the GetMessage call in your main message loop so it can retrieve and dispatch messages for any window in your app.  Even ones you don't know about, there are almost always ones you don't know about.

Comment: @HansPassant In same code if I give second parameter for GetMessage as NULL it get execute correctly but after completion of while loop I tried GetLastError() and it return me error code 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). What is wrong in the loop?

Comment: Calling GetLastError() when there was no error is not sensible and just produces a random number.

Comment: @HansPassant It means GetLastError has implementation problem(bugs).

Comment: No, calling GetLastError when there is no error is a bug in your code.  Winapi functions do not go through the trouble of setting the last error to 0 when they don't fail.

Comment: Yes I Got it. Thanks @HansPassant.