# Handling WinAPI error return values

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling, standards, getlasterror

I am currently learning C++ in connection with WinAPI. I am struggling to come up with meaningful error handling strategy for WinAPI functions.

**PROBLEM:**

Most of WinAPI functions can return 0 in case of error, but in many cases I don't see any information on MSDN as to what could cause such error and how to address / resolve it. Taking `GetCursorPos` as an example:

> Returns nonzero if successful or zero otherwise. To get extended error information, call **[GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)**.
>
> (...)
>
> The input desktop must be the current desktop when you call **GetCursorPos**. Call **[OpenInputDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/ms684309(v=vs.85).aspx)** to determine whether the current desktop is the input desktop. If it is not, call **[SetThreadDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/ms686250(v=vs.85).aspx)** with the **HDESK** returned by **OpenInputDesktop** to switch to that desktop.

- If I follow the route of **GetLastError** I am interested in what errors could be returned by that specific function so that I can inspect what can be done about them. But error codes are organized on this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) into 10 groups based on just error number and without any specification of what errors are listed in which group.
- When I tried to discover how would **OpenInputDesktop** help me make my code more bulletproof I discovered that again:

> If the function fails, the return value is **NULL**. To get extended error information, call **GetLastError**.

**To sum it up:** almost every function in WinAPI can return value determining occurrence of error and I can get information on the error **when it happens** using **GetLastError** function. But no information whatsoever on what kinds of errors I can expect and what steps to make to resolve them.

The examples are many, `GetWindowRect` is also widely used and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) delivers the very same limited information as for `GetCursorPos`.

**QUESTION:**

Please are there any standards on how to approach WinAPI function error return values that would retain error handling from becoming just showing a message box and exiting the application? Thank you!

Comment: In case of both GetWindowRect and GetCursorPos, you only call GetLastError if one of those APIs return FALSE.

Comment: @Asesh Yes, but that only gives me information on what error happened and only when it happens. MSDN is very limited resource in regards to what errors can happen so that I can better understand/decide what my code should do in such case.

Comment: Unless documentation for a given API function explicitly states **specific error codes** that are returned, then you can't rely on particular errors because **ANY** error could be returned. In those cases, you are not supposed to try to recover from them, since you can't know ahead of time why they are failing. You can only possibly recover from known errors. If the API is essential for a given operation to succeed, all you can do it fail the operation, optionally log the error, and move on

Comment: There is no standard. Get familiar with error codes, act accordingly.

Comment: @Ron Could you please be more specific on "get familiar with error codes"? There are 16.000 of them and I honestly don't know where to start, that is why I am asking for standardized approach to them.

Comment: _retain error handling from becoming just showing a message box and exiting the application_ - This dependes on how critical each particular error is for your application. In some cases, you may simply skip the code that depends on the failed API (e. g. GUI drawing code), in other cases you may log the error but without informing the user and for mission-critical APIs you will show an error message in addition to logging. I think your question is too broad to answer specifically.

Comment: When your function returns an error code you should act to prevent it from returning error codes in the future. There is no need to know every error code by heart unless you dwell into some low level Windows internals.

Comment: error codes can be very useful in development stage - this is frequently useful hint, what is going wrong. in release code, also in some situation this can be useful - say you fail open file. and last error say what is happens: - file not exist, path is invalid, share violation, or access denied.

Comment: @Ron Do you mean like during development? Because none of those errors happened to me so far, but I am afraid that when the application reaches other users with different Windows and different PCs then some might occur and that is why I am trying to prevent them as hard as I can.

Comment: Sometimes a) it is more likely that the computer will break than that the error code will be generated and b) there is no realistic way you can recover from the error other than shutting down the program. Check if this applies.

Comment: @zett42 I know this is not the best way to say it, but then if you think about it - when you don't know how severe the impact of error may be since you don't know the exact error ahead, how can you decide whether leaving the app running or closing it is the best option... This is one of the points where I get lost.

Comment: The question essentially boils down to this: How do you transfer control from the point of error discovery to the point of (potential) error handling? C++ uses exceptions for this, `std::system_error` being the most appropriate one in this case. This is necessary, because you generally do not know anything about the implications of an error at the point where it's discovered. The old *"use exceptions in exceptional situations only"* doesn't buy you anything, because at the point where you have to decide, you cannot assess whether this is exceptional or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as knowing ahead of time what possible error codes can be returned by a particular function, I'm afraid that Microsoft decided long time ago that maintaining such documentation for all functions would be too cumbersome and costly, as an API function may call any number of other API functions, which in turn may call others and so on. Sometimes you get lucky and the MSDN doc calls out error codes specific to that function, as is the case with [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) but this is not the case with all functions as you have noticed.

That being said, the standard way of dealing with the error codes returned by `GetLastError()` is to [format them with FormatMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329).

If you passed LANG_USER_DEFAULT for lang ID, this will return the sometimes helpful, sometimes not so helpful error message formatted in the user's chosen locale from the error code. You can show this message to the user. If you wanted to format it in your own language for logging purposes, assuming it's English, you would pass MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US) for lang ID.

And this is the best you can do if the error codes are not documented and you haven't come across them in testing: log them and get the log with other debug info attached to the issue report.

Comment: See [The importance of the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS flag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071128-00/?p=24353). A fully working implementation of `FormatMessage` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329).

Comment: You mention `ReadFile`, which has a bug that annoys me. When reading from the console the docs say "if you press Ctrl+C, the call succeeds, but `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`". Since Windows 8, the last error is 0, which is indistinguishable from the user beginning the line with Ctrl+Z to indicate end of file (i.e. stop reading lines, close the shell, etc). `ReadConsole` sets the error correctly in this case, even though it's not documented for this function; however, it also requires manually implementing Ctrl+Z.