# Converting a c style cast to a proper c++ cast

Tags: c++, winapi, casting

Got this sequence in some code. Looking to convert the c-style cast in the function call to c++ style cast.

```
char* messageBuffer{ nullptr };
const unsigned long size{ FORMAT_MESSAGE(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    0,
    errorMessageID,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL | SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (char*)&messageBuffer,    // this the one want to change
    0,
    0
)};
```

Thanks

Edit: Added the winapi tag for clarity

Comment: Why do you need to cast it?

Comment: Policy - no c-style casts
If you mean why need (char*)&message buffer?

Comment: I did not ask why you want to change c cast, I am asking why do you need cast at all?

Comment: @user3891642 Since you are new, I am going to warn you that might not get good reception of this question. Also, [tour] and [ask].

Comment: If I pass it in with no cast, the call doesn't work. If I try to read messageBuffer, it is empty. Only works with the cast. So, I need to cast, and I need to do it with static_cast, reinterpret_cast, dynamic_cast etc.

Comment: Did you really intend to create a `char*`, then take its address (a `char**`) and pretend that _that_ was a `char*`? Frankly this smells like a bug.

Comment: Aaa, windows, then it is normal...

Comment: Yeah, who knows what crazy stuff windows is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @Lightness: That's the [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) contract, when using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`. Passing the address of a variable for `out` parameters, as well as parameter overloading are common schemes in C interfaces. If that's not something you like, you can hide the details behind a [C++ interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329).

Comment: @snakesAlive: How would you propose to extend an existing API with a C interface, that initially only worked on a caller-provided buffer, with the ability for the implementation to allocate that buffer and pass it to the caller? Note, that you cannot change the signature of a deployed interface.

Comment: @IInspectable: Passing the address of a variable is one thing; lying about its type while doing so is quite another. However, I see that you are correct in saying that this is Microsoft's fault. Yuk!

Comment: @Lightness: How would your proposed alternative look like? It needs to acknowledge the following constraints: expose a C interface, and cannot change parameters, or introduce a new symbol. If you can produce a sufficient answer to address those constraints, then you are free to call it a *"fault"*. If you cannot, then *"fault"* is an inappropriate term.

Comment: @IInspectable: The function should be taking a `char**`, no?

Comment: @Lightness: Right. I assumed, this would be a given, but: You cannot use a time machine either. Anyway, I did point out, that you cannot change parameters. Changing the type obviously violates that constraint. Want to give it another try?

Comment: @IInspectable: I have no idea what you're asking me. I'm saying that Microsoft has sunk us by making this function take the "wrong" type. That's it. Nothing else.

Comment: @Lightness: No, it does not. It takes the correct type, **unless** you specify `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`. This, too, is documented. Did you not bother to read the documentation prior to pointing fingers? Not entirely prudent, now is it?

Comment: @IInspectable: I think this conversation is over...

Comment: @Lightnesss: I acknowledge, that you concede failure to provide an alternative interface, that no one would call *"your fault"* 20 years down the road. You could have been equally vocal about accepting defeat as you were in blaming others. But I'm certainly not fool enough to expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would be:

```
reinterpret_cast<char *>(&messageBuffer)
```

In case any readers are wondering, yes the Windows API function [FormatMessageA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with flag `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` does actually specify this usage.

Note that if `FormatMessageW` is in use, then the cast would be to `wchar_t *`. We can't tell since you have hidden the function name behind this macro `FORMAT_MESSAGE`.

If you are using the normal text macros for Windows API programming then you could instead use:

```
reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&messageBuffer)
```

and should probably also declare `messageBuffer` as either `void *messageBuffer;`, or `LPTSTR messageBuffer;`.

Answer (score 1):

A policy is usually there for a reason and there are two reasons to use C++ casts over C casts.

1. They are safer/stricter because they understand types better.
2. They are easy to do text searches for, unlike C casts.

Number 1 mostly falls out the window if you just slap a `reinterpret_cast` on there to comply with company policy.

I would personally keep the C cast because it is required by the API to cast there when a certain flag is set but I would also try to make it type safe and as strict as possible with something like

```
(LPTSTR)const_cast<LPTSTR*>(&messageBuffer)
```

but if the policy has zero leeway then you can make it fully C++

```
reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(const_cast<LPTSTR*>(&messageBuffer))
```

Comment: Why is the `const_cast` needed at all?

Comment: @IInspectable to make sure the source type is correct before you cast away that type information.

Comment: The source type is appropriately cv-qualified already.

Comment: It is not about cv, it is to catch passing in a completely different type. We want the compiler to verify that we are passing in a pointer to a LPTSTR and const_cast does this.

Comment: That really requires a big fat comment (and an explanation in this answer). Using a [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) for something completely unrelated to its intended purpose (*"Convert[ing] between types with different cv-qualification."*) is not immediately obvious. I for one would be completely confused without a comment.