# C++ Create a handle to a NdisProt driver

Tags: c#, c++, ndis, raw-ethernet

I try to write to a NdisProt driver and send raw ethernet packets. I imported some C++ comands to my C# program, so that I can access the driver. When I try to open a handle to the driver I always get a invalid handle. I already tried it with just "NdisProt" as the path, but it didn't solve it. Do you have any suggestions why i get a invalid handle?

```
private bool OpenDriver()
{
    // User the CreateFile API to open a handle to the file
    this.m_iHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\NdisProt,
    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    // Check to see if we got a valid handle
    if ((int)m_iHandle <= 0)
    {
        // If not, then return false and reset the handle to 0
        this.m_iHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        return false;
    }
```

If you now any other solutions to send raw ethernet packets in a C# program please let me know.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a rights to open this file?

Comment: What do I have to do to get the rights?

Comment: Try to run your application with root-privileges (as admin)

Comment: And check error by GetLastError (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/retrieving-error-messages)

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not fix the problem, when run VS as admin.

Comment: An invalid HANDLE has the integer value -1, so that's what you need to check against rather than any non-positive value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I just solved the problem by adding another  manifest, so that the application is run as admin.

The solution with the NDIS Driver did still not work so I searched for another solution. I found the SharpPcap library. With that library I am able to modify the packets I want to send e.g. change the Destination-MAC-Adress.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

> If you now any other solutions to send raw ethernet packets in a C#
>   program please let me know.

What about [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.7.2) class?

Constructor:

```
public Socket (System.Net.Sockets.SocketType socketType, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType protocolType),
```

where socketType can take the next value: `SocketType.Raw`

Comment: I just want to send packets with a source MAC-Address, a destination MAC-Address and some random data. I guess it is not possible with raw sockets.

Comment: @LeoBiel, ok, you are right. It require to import system C-libraries.

Comment: @LeoBiel, please, check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5292/Raw-Ethernet-Packet-Sending

Comment: thats the basis (codeproject.com/Articles/5292/Raw-Ethernet-Packet-Sending) I'm working on, but I can not get a handle to the ndis driver

Comment: @LeoBiel, so, you should check error (as I said earlier) by GetLastError

Comment: Is there any example how to use GetLastError?

Comment: @LeoBiel, for example: if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == (this.m_iHanle = CreateFile(...)) {  DWORD lastErr = GetLastError(); }

Comment: To retrieve error description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387176/6266408

Answer (score 0):

> If you now any other solutions to send raw ethernet packets in a C# program please let me know.

You can import functions from Windows Winsock library and use [SOCK_RAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) flag when creating a socket.

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
```