# Why EnumProcessModules is return FALSE value and 299 code error?

Tags: c++, winapi

I looked through similar questions, but did not find a solution to my problem.

Exception class:

```
class Exception{
    public:
        Exception(LPCWSTR text){
            QMessageBox::information(0, "Catch",
                                     QString::fromWCharArray(text) + ", Code: " +
                                     QString::number(GetLastError())); 
                     //EnumModules is return FALSE in function getHinstance, Code: 299
        }
}
```

And main code:

```
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, 7068); //PID of opened calculator
    if(handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throw Exception(L"invalid handle in function getHinstance");

    int hNeeded = 1024;
    HINSTANCE hModules[hNeeded];
    DWORD bNeeded = 0;
    PWSTR fileName = new WCHAR[512];
    if(!EnumProcessModulesEx(handle, hModules, sizeof(hModules), &bNeeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL))
        throw Exception(L"EnumModules is return FALSE in function getHinstance");

    for(int i = 0; i < bNeeded / sizeof(HINSTANCE); ++i){
        GetModuleBaseNameW(handle, hModules[i], fileName, sizeof(WCHAR) * 512);
        if(lstrcmpW(fileName, moduleName) == 0){
            delete [] fileName;
            return hModules[i];
        }
    }
```

handle is a valid value of handle process

This code executes in a 64 bit process to enum modules in a 64 bit process

Comment: 299 is `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. Sounds like your `hModules` array is not big enough. What's in `bNeeded`?

Comment: @kichik bNeeded contains "0" value at the time of the exception

Comment: You can't know the error code because you don't call GetLastError. Show a [mcve].

Comment: Does this really compile? I know that `int hNeeded = 1024; HINSTANCE hModules[hNeeded];` is valid C, but it should not compile as C++!?

Comment: @WernerHenze Size of array is known for compiler, it isn't error

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added an example with the code

Comment: Who knows where the handle comes from? For instance. [mcve] please. Why do we have to say that over and over?

Comment: the number of the error code isn't very informative. You should print the error message associated with the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror

Comment: @bolov first comment tells us that info

Comment: @sddvxd the code in the question is not a [MCVE]. Please provide a stand alone console sample (witout QT etc.)

Comment: @sddvxd Just tested it, MSVC says "error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant". I bet you are using gcc and using a gcc language dialect but not a standard C++ language dialect. It would compile though if `hNeeded` were `constexpr`.

Comment: @WernerHenze value of hNeeded is known for compiler, because expression “1024” is a literal constant. And GCC success compile this code

Comment: This has nothing to do with the 1024 literal, since it is being assigned to a variable that is not used to allocate the array until runtime. The compiler doesn't care about the actual value. The code is trying to allocate a Variable-Length Array (VLA), which is a C feature that is implemented as a **non-standard** compiler extension in C++, and few C++ compilers actually implement it. GCC is one of them, MSVC is not. In C++, the *correct and portable* way to allocate an array whose size is only known at runtime is to use `new T[]`, `std::vector<T>`, or `std::make_unique<T[]>()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299) error when running the following code as a 64 bit process.

```
HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 17152); //PID of opened notepad.exe
DWORD errCode = GetLastError();

HMODULE hModules[100];
DWORD bNeeded = 0;
EnumProcessModulesEx(handle, hModules, sizeof(hModules), &bNeeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL);
errCode = GetLastError();
```

And solve the error when use **LIST_MODULES_64BIT** instead of LIST_MODULES_ALL.

My notepad.exe is a 64 bit process.

So it seems you need use LIST_MODULES_64BIT for enumerating the modules of a 64-bit process when use EnumProcessModulesEx.

Or you can use EnumProcessModules:

```
EnumProcessModules(handle, hModules, sizeof(hModules), &bNeeded);
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve my problem:
CreateProcess is returns without waiting for the creation process

My fault is that I did not let the community understand the real context of the program, but provided only a small piece of code that was not related to the problem. Thank you all for the comments, I will try to ask more detailed questions