# Can we throw CWin32Error and an additional parameter with the filename

Tags: exception, mfc, throw

I am using [`CWin32Error`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1025/Do-Not-Call-GetLastError) for exception handling. For example, this is a bit of code from `InstallApplicationFiles` (this method attempts to copy a series of files from the common data folder to the user data folder. It also checks timestamps of files if they both exist):

```cpp
if (!PathFileExists(strUserFilePath))
{
    // We must copy the default file
    if (!PathFileExists(strCommonFilePath))
    {
        // This should not happen as it is installed by the installer! Raise exception
        throw CWin32Error();
    }

    if (!::CopyFile(strCommonFilePath, strUserFilePath, FALSE))
    {
        // There was a problem copying the file! Raise exception
        throw CWin32Error();
    }
}
```

The calling code:

```cpp
try
{
    InstallApplicationFiles();
}
catch (CWin32Error e)
{
    // This exception will be raised for PathFileExist, CopyFile, DeleteFile
    CString strError = _T("");
    strError.Format(_T("Installing application files.\n\nError: %s"), (LPCTSTR)e);
    AfxMessageBox(strError, MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    return FALSE; // Unable to proceed
}
```

The problem is the time the exception is caught we no longer know which file it has a problem with. The error message just states what the error was but it does not state with what file. Is there a way to throw a `CWin32Error` with a parameter stating what file caused the error?

Comment: You cannot amend data when the interface doesn't allow for it. If you need to communicate additional data, you cannot use `CWin32Error`. But C++ allows you to throw objects of *any* type as an exception, so you can easily create your own file exception class that suits your needs (e.g. by deriving from `CWin32Error`). I'd probably use [std::system_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) in place of `CWin32Error`, and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387064/1889329) for message formatting.

Comment: Ok. On reflection I can just do the error handling inside the method and just return false rather than throw.

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't recommend it. Assuming that you have derived `CWin32FileError` from `CWin32Error`, you can also filter on the exception type in your catch clause, e.g. `catch(CWin32FileError const& e) { /* Construct error message using additional information */ } catch(CWin32Error const& e) { /* Perform generic error reporting */ }`. As long as you list more derived types ahead of their base types, everything works as expected, and you get access to the full fidelity of the derived type in your catch clause.

Comment: In this case I would throw [`std::filesystem::filesystem_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error), which has constructors that take one or two file paths in addition to an error code and a descriptive message. Requires C++17 though.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the suggestion. I just derived my own class from `CWin32Error` which suited my needs.