# Failed with error 87: The parameter is incorrect. How to determine which parameter is incorrect?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a win32 window as simple as possible, in a unit test, but I get an error 87: how do I get which parameter is incorrect ?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

LPTSTR GetErrorMessage(wstring fnName)
{
    LPTSTR messageBuffer{};
    LPTSTR displayBuffer{};
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        0, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, 0);

    displayBuffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, lstrlen(messageBuffer) + (fnName.size() + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf(displayBuffer, LocalSize(displayBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR), L"%s failed with error %d: %s", fnName.c_str(), dw, messageBuffer);

    return displayBuffer;
}

TEST_METHOD(WinTest)
{
    auto hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, 0, L"test w", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Assert::IsNotNull(hwnd, GetErrorMessage(L"CreateWindowExW"));

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

> Assert failed. CreateWindowExW failed with error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

Reference: [createwindowexw on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw)

Comment: class name can not be 0

Comment: @walnut Right. I edited following your advice to remove this distraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the *specific* question you asked - the Win32 API does not tell you *WHICH* parameter is invalid. You have to read the documentation for the function that failed, and then debug your code to compare the values you are actually passing to the function to see how they differ from the acceptable values the function is expecting.

In this *particular* example, you are passing a NULL pointer to the `lpClassName` parameter of `CreateWindowEx()`, which is not allowed. You must specify the name of the window class you want to create.

---

On a side note, your `GetErrorMessage()` function is leaking memory, as it does not free the memory allocated by either `FormatMessage()` or `LocalAlloc()`. Both `messageBuffer` and `displayBuffer` need to be freed with `LocalFree()`.

I strongly advise you to make `GetErrorMessage()` return a `wstring` instead of a raw `TCHAR*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
wstring GetErrorMessage(const wstring &fnName)
{
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    wostringstream displayBuffer;
    displayBuffer << fnName << L" failed with error " << dw;

    LPWSTR messageBuffer{};
    if (FormatMessageW(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        0,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPWSTR)&messageBuffer,
        0,
        0))
    {
        displayBuffer << L": " << messageBuffer;
        LocalFree(messageBuffer);
    }

    return displayBuffer.str();
}
```

Comment: This is calling `GetLastError` potentially too late. The error code **must** be an input to the function. And the implementation still leaks memory, for different reasons. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565001/1889329) for a robust implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable it would leak only if the `displayBuffer` throws an exception, which would be rare, if ever.

Comment: Leaking memory when memory has become scarce is probably not a sustainable strategy. Certainly not when you're writing diagnostic code. And while you don't know the environment where this code winds up running in, you cannot make any assumptions about it either (like the implied one, that the target system isn't prepared to deal with low-memory situations anyway).