# boost::asio with named pipes; parent process can't read from pipe via async_read_some

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

## Problem Statement

I have a windows server/parent process that creates two named pipes, one inbound and one outbound. Then it spins up a client/child process and gives those pipe names to that child process, which connects to them.

The child process is able to successfully read and write to the pipes asynchronously. The parent process is able to write to the outbound pipe, but fails to read from the inbound pipe (my code times out after 2.5 seconds).

### Expected Output

The output I expect from the whole shebang is:

```
Writing {Hello pipes!} asynchronously to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut}
Reading asynchronously from {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
Wrote {12} bytes to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut}
Started read + write
Read {21} bytes, msg {Goodbye cruel world! } from {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
Finished waiting for write
Wrote to pipe!
Finished waiting for read
Received {Goodbye cruel world! }
Child stdout: {
        Connecting to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut} and {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
        Wrote {21} bytes asynchronously to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
        Read {12} bytes asynchronously from {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut}
        Write handler completed
        Read handler completed
        Got {Hello pipes!}
        Exiting


Child stderr: {
```

### Actual Output

The output I get instead is:

```
Writing {Hello pipes!} asynchronously to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut}
Reading asynchronously from {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
Wrote {12} bytes to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut}
Started read + write
Finished waiting for write
Wrote to pipe!
Finished waiting for read
Got exception {Timed out trying to read from pipe}
Child stdout: {
        Connecting to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut} and {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
        Wrote {21} bytes asynchronously to {\\.\pipe\processWrapperIn}
        Read {12} bytes asynchronously from {\\.\pipe\processWrapperOut}
        Write handler completed
        Read handler completed
        Got {Hello pipes!}
        Exiting


Child stderr: {
```

## Complete Code

What follows is the complete code. I tried to boil this down to as little code as I could, even going so far as to remove error checking from the cases where I'm not seeing errors.

#### Parent process

```
/// AsyncPipeServer.cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <windows.h>

#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <boost/winapi/handle_info.hpp>
//
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/basic_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/windows/stream_handle.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/child.hpp>
#include <boost/process/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/process/extend.hpp>
#include <boost/process/group.hpp>
#include <boost/process/io.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)

boost::asio::windows::stream_handle CreateStreamHandle(
    const std::string& pipeName,
    DWORD openFlags,
    OVERLAPPED& overlapped,
    boost::asio::io_context& ioContext);
void SetToDieWithParent(HANDLE& localHandle);
std::string GetErrorAsString(const DWORD errorMessageID);
std::string ChangeNewlines(std::string input);

class ProcessWrapper
{
public:
    explicit ProcessWrapper(const std::string& cmdToLaunch)
        : m_cmdToLaunch(cmdToLaunch)
        , m_inPipeName{ "\\\\.\\pipe\\processWrapperIn" }
        , m_outPipeName{ "\\\\.\\pipe\\processWrapperOut" }
    {
    }

    ~ProcessWrapper()
    {
        try
        {
            m_ioContext.stop();
            m_ioThread.join();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        m_inPipe = CreateStreamHandle(m_inPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, m_inOverlapped, m_ioContext);
        assert(m_inPipe->is_open());

        m_outPipe = CreateStreamHandle(m_outPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, m_outOverlapped, m_ioContext);
        assert(m_outPipe->is_open());

        const auto cmd{ m_cmdToLaunch + " " + m_outPipeName + " " + m_inPipeName };

        HANDLE localHandle = nullptr;
        SetToDieWithParent(localHandle);
        m_group = std::make_unique<boost::process::group>(localHandle);
        m_child = std::make_unique<boost::process::child>(
            cmd,
            boost::process::std_in.close(),
            boost::process::std_out > m_stdOutput,  //so it can be written without anything
            boost::process::std_err > m_stdError,
            m_errorCode);
        if (!m_errorCode)
        {
            m_group->add(*m_child.get(), m_errorCode);
        }

        m_ioThread = std::thread{ [ctx = &m_ioContext, this] {
            while (this->IsRunning())
            {
                ctx->run();
            }
        } };
    }

    bool IsRunning()
    {
        if (!m_child)
            return false;
        return m_child->running(m_errorCode);
    }

    std::string SyncGetStdOut()
    {
        return GetPipeStreamImpl(m_stdOutput, m_output);
    }

    std::string SyncGetStdError()
    {
        return GetPipeStreamImpl(m_stdError, m_error);
    }

    std::future<bool> WriteToPipe(const std::string& msg)
    {
        auto promise{ std::make_shared<std::promise<bool>>() };
        if (!m_outPipe)
        {
            promise->set_value(false);
            return promise->get_future();
        }

        assert(m_outPipe->is_open());
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Writing {" << msg << "} asynchronously to {" << m_outPipeName << "}\n";
            std::cout << ss.str();
        }

        const auto buffPtr{ std::make_shared<boost::asio::const_buffer>(msg.c_str(), msg.length()) };

        m_outPipe->async_write_some(
            *buffPtr,
            [pipeName = m_outPipeName, promise, buffPtr](
                const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes_written) {
                if (ec)
                {
                    std::stringstream ss{};
                    ss << "Had error writing {" << ec.message() << "} to {" << pipeName << "}";
                    std::cerr << ss.str() << '\n';
                    promise->set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error{ ss.str() }));
                }
                else
                {
                    {
                        std::stringstream ss;
                        ss << "Wrote {" << bytes_written << "} bytes to {" << pipeName << "}\n";
                        std::cout << ss.str();
                    }
                    promise->set_value(true);
                }
            });
        return promise->get_future();
    }

    std::future<boost::optional<std::string>> ReadFromPipe()
    {
        auto promise{ std::make_shared<std::promise<boost::optional<std::string>>>() };
        if (!m_inPipe)
        {
            promise->set_value({});
            return promise->get_future();
        }
        assert(m_inPipe->is_open());
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Reading asynchronously from {" << m_inPipeName << "}\n";
            std::cout << ss.str();
        }
        constexpr auto size{ 256 };
        auto buff{ std::make_shared<boost::asio::streambuf>() };
        m_inPipe->async_read_some(
            buff->prepare(size),
            [pipeName = m_inPipeName, promise, buff, size](
                const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                try
                {
                    if (ec)
                    {
                        std::stringstream ss{};
                        ss << "Had error reading {" << ec.message() << "} from {" << pipeName << "}";
                        std::cerr << ss.str() << '\n';
                        promise->set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error{ ss.str() }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buff->commit(bytes_transferred);
                        std::istream is{ buff.get() };
                        std::string retval{};
                        retval.resize(size);
                        is.read(&retval.front(), size);
                        retval.resize(is.gcount());
                        {
                            std::stringstream ss;
                            ss << "Read {" << bytes_transferred << "} bytes, msg {" << retval << "} from {" << pipeName
                               << "}\n";
                            std::cout << ss.str();
                        }
                        promise->set_value(retval);
                    }
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    promise->set_exception(std::current_exception());
                }
            });
        return promise->get_future();
    }

private:
    std::string m_cmdToLaunch;

    boost::asio::io_context m_ioContext;
    std::thread m_ioThread;

    std::string m_inPipeName;
    OVERLAPPED m_inOverlapped{};
    boost::optional<boost::asio::windows::stream_handle> m_inPipe;
    std::string m_outPipeName;
    OVERLAPPED m_outOverlapped{};
    boost::optional<boost::asio::windows::stream_handle> m_outPipe;

    boost::process::ipstream m_stdOutput;
    std::string m_output;
    boost::process::ipstream m_stdError;
    std::string m_error;

    std::unique_ptr<boost::process::child> m_child;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::process::group> m_group;
    std::error_code m_errorCode;

    std::string GetPipeStreamImpl(boost::process::ipstream& stream, std::string& errorOrOutput)
    {
        if (!m_child)
        {
            return errorOrOutput;
        }
        m_child->wait();
        std::string line{};
        while (std::getline(stream, line))
        {
            errorOrOutput += line;
        }
        m_stdOutput.pipe().close();
        return errorOrOutput;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ProcessWrapper process("AsyncPipeMain.exe");
    process.Start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 50 });
    try
    {
        auto write{ process.WriteToPipe("Hello pipes!") };
        auto msg{ process.ReadFromPipe() };
        std::cout << "Started read + write\n";

        const auto writeReady{ write.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 250 }) };
        std::cout << "Finished waiting for write\n";
        if (writeReady != std::future_status::ready)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Timed out trying to write to pipe" };
        }
        const auto writeVal{ write.get() };
        std::cout << (writeVal ? "Wrote to pipe!\n" : "Did not write to pipe!\n");

        const auto readReady{ msg.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 250 }) };
        std::cout << "Finished waiting for read\n";
        if (readReady != std::future_status::ready)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Timed out trying to read from pipe" };
        }
        const auto msgVal{ msg.get() };
        if (msgVal)
        {
            std::cout << "Received {" << msgVal.value() << "}\n";
            //assert("Goodbye cruel world!" == msgVal.value());
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Didn't receive a msg\n";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Got exception {" << e.what() << "}\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Child stdout: {\n";
    std::cout << '\t' << ChangeNewlines(process.SyncGetStdOut()) << "\n}\n";
    std::cout << "Child stderr: {\n";
    std::cerr << '\t' << ChangeNewlines(process.SyncGetStdError()) << "\n}\n";
}

boost::asio::windows::stream_handle CreateStreamHandle(
    const std::string& pipeName,
    DWORD openFlags,
    OVERLAPPED& overlapped,
    boost::asio::io_context& ioContext)
{
    auto* const inHandle{ CreateNamedPipeA(
        pipeName.c_str(), openFlags | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0, PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 8192, 8192, 0, nullptr) };

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == inHandle)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "could not open pipe" };
    }

    const auto inConnected{ ConnectNamedPipe(inHandle, &overlapped) };

    const auto lastErr{ ::GetLastError() };
    if (0 != inConnected || ERROR_IO_PENDING != lastErr && ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED != lastErr)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "could not connect to pipe" };
    }

    return { ioContext, inHandle };
}

void SetToDieWithParent(HANDLE& localHandle)
{
    assert(!localHandle);
    localHandle = CreateJobObject(nullptr, nullptr);
    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jobInfo;
    memset(&jobInfo, 0, sizeof(jobInfo));
    jobInfo.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags |= JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
    if (!SetInformationJobObject(localHandle, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jobInfo, sizeof(jobInfo)))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Internal error: Could not set up job object to handle");
    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387176/2025214
//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
std::string GetErrorAsString(const DWORD errorMessageID)
{
    if (errorMessageID == 0)
    {
        return std::string();  //No error message has been recorded
    }
    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        errorMessageID,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&messageBuffer),
        0,
        NULL);
    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);
    return message;
}

//throwaway function to make output legible
std::string ChangeNewlines(std::string input)
{
    for (auto newline{ input.find("\r") }; newline != input.npos; newline = input.find("\r", newline + 1))
    {
        input[newline] = '\n';
        input.insert(newline + 1, "\t");
    }
    return input;
}
```

#### Child Process

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/asio/windows/stream_handle.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>

std::string GetErrorAsString(DWORD errorMessageID);
boost::asio::windows::stream_handle CreateStreamHandle(
    boost::string_view pipeName,
    DWORD accessFlag,
    boost::asio::io_context& ioContext);

int main(const int argc, const char* const* const argv)
{
    std::cout << "Connecting to {" << argv[1] << "} and {" << argv[2] << "}\n";
    const boost::string_view inPipeName{ argv[1] };
    const boost::string_view outPipeName{ argv[2] };
    boost::asio::io_context io{};

    try
    {
        auto in{ CreateStreamHandle(inPipeName, GENERIC_READ, io) };
        auto out{ CreateStreamHandle(outPipeName, GENERIC_WRITE, io) };

        boost::system::error_code inError{};
        std::array<char, 256> buffer{ '\0' };
        std::atomic<size_t> bytesWritten{};
        boost::asio::mutable_buffer buff{ buffer.data(), buffer.size() };
        std::atomic<bool> finishedReading{ false };
        in.async_read_some(
            buff,
            [inPipeName, &finishedReading, &inError, &bytesWritten](
                const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                std::cout << "Read {" << bytes_transferred << "} bytes asynchronously from {" << inPipeName << "}\n";
                bytesWritten.store(bytes_transferred);
                finishedReading.store(true);
            });

        boost::system::error_code outError{};
        std::atomic<bool> finishedWriting{ false };
        constexpr auto outMsg{ "Goodbye cruel world!" };
        const boost::asio::const_buffer outBuff{ outMsg, 21 };
        out.async_write_some(
            outBuff,
            [outPipeName, &finishedWriting, &outError](
                const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes_written) {
                std::cout << "Wrote {" << bytes_written << "} bytes asynchronously to {" << outPipeName << "}\n";
                finishedWriting.store(true);
            });

        const auto start{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
        const auto end{ start + std::chrono::seconds{ 5 } };
        auto current{ start };
        const auto step{ (end - start) / 100 };

        std::thread ioThread{ [end, &io, &finishedReading, &finishedWriting] {
            while (std::chrono::system_clock::now() < end && (!finishedReading.load() || !finishedWriting.load()))
            {
                io.run();
            }
        } };

        while (!finishedReading.load() || !finishedWriting.load())
        {
            const auto now{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
            if (end < now)
            {
                std::cout << "\n";
                break;
            }
            if ((current + step) < now)
            {
                current = now;
                std::cout << " .";
            }
        }

        if (finishedWriting.load())
        {
            std::cout << "Write handler completed\n";
        }

        if (finishedReading.load())
        {
            std::cout << "Read handler completed\n";
            std::cout << "Got {";
            std::cout.write(buffer.data(), bytesWritten.load());
            std::cout << "}\n";
        }

        io.stop();
        ioThread.join();
        std::cout << "Exiting\n";

        if (finishedReading.load() && !inError && finishedWriting.load() && !outError)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught exception {" << e.what() << "}\n";
        return -1;
    }
}

boost::asio::windows::stream_handle CreateStreamHandle(
    const boost::string_view pipeName,
    const DWORD accessFlag,
    boost::asio::io_context& ioContext)
{
    const auto inHandle{
        CreateFileA(
            pipeName.data(),       // pipe name
            accessFlag,            // access
            0,                     // no sharing
            NULL,                  // default security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING,         // opens existing pipe
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,  // async
            NULL)                  // no template file
    };

    return { ioContext, inHandle };
}

//note that GetErrorAsString is also needed in this main
```

Comment: Why are you combining a dozen different approaches? Speicifically, why use async and syncronous streams at the same time? Why use Boost's async_pipe as well as your own named pipes? Is there anything not done by Boost Process's pipes? Or getting from the other angle: what are you trying to achieve, and does Boost add anything?

Comment: Hey sehe, thanks for stopping by.

All the code in this question is using `boost::asio::windows::stream_handle` and calling the `async_*_some` APIs. I understand the confusion, since I included the `async_pipe.hpp` header (will edit that out) but you will note that I am not actually using them in the code (I was using them in place of `stream_handle` in my first try, but they didn't work at all).

What I am trying to achieve is use named pipes asynchronously on Windows (and eventually Unix) without writing the low-level code myself. `boost::asio` is the first thing I am trying.

Comment: I suspect that `async_read_some` is swallowing errors. When I try to peek at the pipe from another thread while waiting for the read to time out, I get "pipe closed" errors. But `async_read_some` claims that it will surface any errors it gets from the APIs. Why isn't it telling me that the pipe is closed?

Under the hypothesis that maybe the synchronous API would give me the errors, I wrote the code in my "answer" and then it turned out that code *worked*, which didn't get me any closer to finding out why the async API isn't working.

Comment: I think async_pipe should just work (it uses `stream_handle` internally anyways, and saves you all the trouble of setting up the pipes). If it doesn't, that's annoying - it could be something straightforward. I don't have a winodws environment so I don't think I'll be able to look at it in reasonable time frame

Comment: Also, `async_read_some` is not swallowing errors. If it does, that's a bug (or the handle assigned to `stream_handle` doesn't meet some documented criterium?)

Comment: @sehe `async_pipe ... saves you all the trouble of setting up the pipes` This was part of the problem, I think. It sets the pipes up to be used a certain way, which was not the way I wanted. I looked at the code, and it does not match any of the examples of how to set up named pipes in Windows that I could find. There is also no way in the `async_pipe` API to distinguish between read-only access, write-only access, or duplex acces; not to mention server vs. client. I think it was designed to be used in a very specific way, and that way is not the way I wanted.

Comment: "It sets the pipes up to be used a certain way, which was not the way I wanted" - perhaps you should elaborate on exactly what way you want to use them. I imagine Boost Project **does** want to use them for stdin/stdout/stderr redirection, mainly.

Comment: As my example code implies, I want to use named pipes for IPC. Typical IPC with named pipes (on Windows, at least) involves a "server" and a "client" which use different APIs; the "server" creates the named pipe and then waits for a connection from a client. The "client" connects to an already extant named pipe. This is the kind of behavior I'm looking for (a parent process spawning a child process) and is essentially what my code in this question does using `stream_handle`s. And it mostly works! Except for the read on the server side.

Comment: `Also, async_read_some is not swallowing errors.` Perhaps not, but when I try to Peek at the contents of the pipe while waiting for my async read operation to complete, I get a "pipe closed" error and my async read operation times out before completing *or* giving me any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228927/discussion-between-sehe-and-caps).

Answer (score 0):

### Working alternative solution

I have discovered that the non-async version of `read_some` *does* work with this code:

```
    std::future<boost::optional<std::string>> ReadFromPipe()
    {
        auto promise{ std::make_shared<std::promise<boost::optional<std::string>>>() };
        if (!m_inPipe)
        {
            promise->set_value({});
            return promise->get_future();
        }
        assert(m_inPipe->is_open());
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Reading asynchronously from {" << m_inPipeName << "}\n";
            std::cout << ss.str();
        }
        constexpr auto size{ 256 };
        auto buff{ std::make_shared<boost::asio::streambuf>() };
        m_inPipe->async_read_some(
            buff->prepare(size),
            [pipeName = m_inPipeName, promise, buff, size](
                const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                try
                {
                    if (ec)
                    {
                        std::stringstream ss{};
                        ss << "Had error reading {" << ec.message() << "} from {" << pipeName << "}";
                        std::cerr << ss.str() << '\n';
                        promise->set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error{ ss.str() }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buff->commit(bytes_transferred);
                        std::istream is{ buff.get() };
                        std::string retval{};
                        retval.resize(size);
                        is.read(&retval.front(), size);
                        retval.resize(is.gcount());
                        {
                            std::stringstream ss;
                            ss << "Read {" << bytes_transferred << "} bytes, msg {" << retval << "} from {" << pipeName
                               << "}\n";
                            std::cout << ss.str();
                        }
                        promise->set_value(retval);
                    }
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    promise->set_exception(std::current_exception());
                }
            });
        return promise->get_future();
    }
```

but I would prefer to use the `async_read_some` method instead.