# How to get an error message box when LoadLibrary fails?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, loadlibrary

I want the proc to show detailed information such as which dependency is missing, whether the dll is invalid...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Record original error mode
    UINT prevErrorMode = GetErrorMode();
    ::SetErrorMode(0);

    std::wstring wstr;

    // Get library absolute path and store into wstr.
    // ...

    typedef int (*EntryFun)(int, char *[]);

    HINSTANCE hDLL = ::LoadLibraryW(wstr.data());
    int res = -1;
    if (hDLL != NULL) {
        EntryFun fun = (EntryFun)::GetProcAddress(hDLL, "main_entry");
        if (fun != NULL) {
            // Restore error mode
            SetErrorMode(prevErrorMode);

            res = fun(argc, argv);
        } else {
            res = ::GetLastError();
            ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, TO_UNICODE("Failed to find entry!"), TO_UNICODE("Error"),
                          MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        ::FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    } else {
        res = ::GetLastError();
        ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, TO_UNICODE("Failed to load main module!"), TO_UNICODE("Error"),
                      MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I use `SetErrorMode` but it doesn't seem to work, there's no message box after LoadLibrary returns `NULL`.

Also, `FormatMessage` doesn't help because it cannot provide information about which dependency is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the error message from the error code returned by GetLastError()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror)

Comment: What happens when you run this single-stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: I don't see any code here that attempts to convert the error message into a string.  MessageBoxW will only show the strings you pass as arguments, it doesn't just guess what you want to display.  Also, looking at the documentation of SetErrorMode, I don't think it has anything to do with LoadLibrary so I'm not sure why you are trying to use it.

Comment: Sound like the program could be crashing

Comment: "*I want the proc to show detailed information such as which dependency is missing*" - unfortunately, the Win32 API simply doesn't provide that level of detail. If you try to load a DLL and it has a dependency on a missing DLL/export, all the API will tell you is "module not found" or "procedure not found", but not WHICH one. The only way to get that kind of information is to basically write your own loader to walk through the dependencies yourself until you find what is missing.

Comment: Only the message box I added in the code shows.

Comment: I've heard that if I set the error mode to 0, then a dialog will exec by Windows automatically.

Comment: Windows will show a dialog for a missing dependency when starting a process, but not for a subsequent call to LoadLibrary once the process is up and running.

Comment: A couple things - try just the library name instead of full path, but make sure the DLL is in same dir as the executable, or in the system path. Then, instead of trying TO_UNICODE, try hardcoding unicode strings instead just as a test - L"string". This may then better reveal the failure.

Answer (score 0):

[LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw#return-value) reports error through [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). The advantage of [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking) is *Run-time dynamic linking enables the process to continue running even if a DLL is not available*. You may write your own loader to walk through the dependencies yourself until you find what is missing as @RemyLebeau said. There is a [MemoryModule](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule) repository which loads a DLL completely from memory and you can refer to.

But for [Load-Time Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking), *the system simply terminates the process if it cannot find the DLL*.
[image]

Comment: I only wish Windows to show this dialog when LoadLibrary fails.

Comment: When the dialog is showed, the process was terminated. You may write your own loader to load libraries.