# How to call "StrCpyW" function from "shlwapi.dll"? in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, strcpy

I use Code::Blocks as IDE.

And I should use `"libshlwapi.a"` library in order to use `"StrCpyW"` function.

But I want to use that function without the library.

In order to achieve that, I should call `"shlwapi.dll"`.

So, I write my codes like this:

```
void StrCpyW(PWSTR a_wcResultString, PCWSTR p_cwcSourceString)
{
    typedef PWSTR (*tdStrCpyW)(PWSTR, PCWSTR);

    HMODULE hmShlwapi;

    hmShlwapi = LoadLibraryW(L"shlwapi.dll");

    if(hmShlwapi)
    {
        tdStrCpyW fnStrCpyW = (tdStrCpyW)GetProcAddress(hmShlwapi, "StrCpyW");

        fnStrCpyW(a_wcResultString, p_cwcSourceString);
    }

    FreeLibrary(hmShlwapi);
}
```

So, what is wrong in my codes?

Comment: Obviously missing part: At which point does it fail? And if it is one of the Windows API functions, use GetLastError to get the error code and FormatMessage to get a pretty error message from it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror

Comment: What fails when you do what? Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: You still have not explained what happened when you ran your code. If you got an error please post the exact text of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [wcscpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscpy) instead so you don't have to load any libraries.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed my problem. Still, I should learn dll calling in order to bypass library dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tdStrCpyW` type is missing the `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`) calling convention:

```
typedef PWSTR (WINAPI *tdStrCpyW)(PWSTR, PCWSTR);
               ^^^^^^
```

Most Win32 APIs on Windows use `__stdcall`. Only a handful of functions, mainly those that have C-style variadic parameters, such as `wsprintf(A/W)`, use `__cdecl` instead. This detail tends to be omitted in MSDN documentation.

Also, you are not checking if `GetProcAddress()` fails.  And your call to `FreeLibrary()` is in the wrong place if `LoadLibraryW()` fails.

Try this:

```
void StrCpyW(PWSTR a_wcResultString, PCWSTR p_cwcSourceString)
{
    typedef PWSTR (WINAPI *tdStrCpyW)(PWSTR, PCWSTR);

    HMODULE hmShlwapi = LoadLibraryW(L"shlwapi.dll");
    if (hmShlwapi)
    {
        tdStrCpyW fnStrCpyW = (tdStrCpyW) GetProcAddress(hmShlwapi, "StrCpyW");
        if (fnStrCpyW)
            fnStrCpyW(a_wcResultString, p_cwcSourceString);

        FreeLibrary(hmShlwapi);
    }
}
```