# What Windows system error codes can GetCurrentDirectory() set, and how to interpret them?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, error-handling

I'm trying to implement error handlers for possible [Windows system errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) that the [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function might set to the last-error code.

The documentation only says:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

But that list is huge, and I couldn't find any information about which error states are actually possible, and how to interpret them in the context.

**EDIT:**

I tried to produce an error state other than the buffer size, and tested both `GetCurrentDirectory()` and `getcwd()`.

Setting the current directory to a removable drive, then removing the drive and querying afterwards didn't result in any errors; both returned the removable drive's path with no error indication, even after it's been removed.

Setting the current directory to a path where one of it's ancestors denies the current user all rights didn't result in any errors; both returned the drive's path with no error indication..

Comment: If it's an error you expect, handle it appropriately. You don't need to know about what errors could happen, there is no exhaustive list (and it could change based on various circumstances). Just make sure to also handle unexpected errors. If you need a way to get the (localized) error message for an error you didn't expect to display it to a user, check out `FormatMessage`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387064/how-to-get-the-error-message-from-the-error-code-returned-by-getlasterror

Comment: @CherryDT That's my problem - i don't know what to expect. Naively i assumed that it's guaranteed that there will always be a current directory for every windows process and have no clue what to expect. My goal is to offer the users hints about how to recover from specific errors.

Comment: The best solution here really is to stop using `GetCurrentDirectory()` altogether. It cannot be made to return reliable results, and the results it returns are of no practical value.

Comment: @IInspectable Can you elaborate? Is this because of issues with libraries and multithreading and also no other similar function like [`getcwd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) or [`std::filesystem::current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) should be used or because the specific implementation of `GetCurrentDirectory` by MS?

Comment: It is the particular issue of storing global state in a multithreaded world. All implementations mentioned share the unreliability.

Comment: If a process can't tell you what its current directory is, I'd have it insta-terminate

Comment: With such basic `GetXxx` calls, I would normally handle only `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` which could happen when the thing you check changed to something longer between your first call (to determine length) and your second call (to load the actual data). However, `GetCurrentDirectory` works differently, unfortunately... Instead of checking an error, you would need to check whether the return value is greater than the buffer length. So I would consider - in this particular case - _all_ errors unexpected and just abort whatever action you/the user was trying to do. It is very unlikely to fail.

Comment: @CherryDT i usually avoid this by hoping that MAX_PATH is always enough. What the docs about `GetCurrentDirectory` don't mention is what they're doing now or in the future to get the path. If it's just a string copy (or concatenation) then the buffer size is the only concern but it they're actually testing the path's availability or similar things then there might be error states with could occur frequently. I tested a removable drive theory with `GetCurrentDirectory` and `getcwd` but both return the removable drives path with no error indication even after it's been removed.

Comment: @ridilculous the problem with `GetCurrentDirectory` specifically is that by the time `GetCurrentDirectory` returns the current directory may already have changed.  So anything you are planning to do with the path to the current directory will no longer be correct.  Also any call into a library function may change the current directory.

Comment: @ridilculous "*i usually avoid this by hoping that MAX_PATH is always enough*" - it is not, especially in the presence of a ```\\?\``` prefixed path, or the use of a `longPathAware` app manifest. "*If it's just a string copy (or concatenation)*" - it is. "*but if they're actually testing the path's availability*" - they're not. That happens when the path is actually used in a file I/O call, like `CreateFile()`. The CWD itself is ignorant of that, it is just a global string, nothing more.

Comment: I don't think there are any errors, returned by `GetCurrentDirectory`, that applications need to recover from except what `GetCurrentDirectory` says, *Multithreaded applications and shared library code should not use the
GetCurrentDirectory function and should avoid using relative path names*.